# C++ constructor syntax

Tags: c++, constructor

Simple question: are the following statements equivalent? or is the second one doing more implicit things behind the scenes (if so, what?)

```
myClass x(3);
myClass x = myClass(3);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They are not completely identical. The first is called "direct initialization" while the second is called "copy initialization".

Now, the Standard makes up two rules. The first is for direct initialization and for copy initialization where the initializer is of the type of the initialized object. The second rule is for copy initialization in other cases.

So, from that point of view both are termed in one - the first - rule. In the case where you have copy initialization with the same type, the compiler is allowed to elide a copy, so it can construct the temporary you create directly into the initialized object. So you can end up very well with the same code generated. But the copy constructor, even if the copy is elided (optimized out), must still be available. I.e if you have a private copy constructor, that code is invalid if the code in which it appears has no access to it.

The second is called copy-initialization, because if the type of the initializer is of a different type, a temporary object is created in trying to implicitly convert the right side to the left side:

```
myclass c = 3;
```

The compiler creates a temporary object of the type of myclass then when there is a constructor that takes an int. Then it initializes the object with that temporary. Also in this case, the temporary created can be created directly in the initialized object. You can follow these steps by printing messages in constructors / destructors of your class and using the option `-fno-elide-constructors` for GCC. It does not try to elide copies then.

On a side-note, that code above has nothing to do with an assignment operator. In both cases, what happens is an initialization.

Comment: with VC9 "myclass c = 3" seems to just call "myclass(int x)" directly, rather than a using a temporary myclass object.

Comment: VC is broken in this regard.  It has a rule similar to: "Use direct initialization wherever possible".

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explain, actually I've read Scott Meyer and Herb Sutter's discuss about this topic, but failed to verify it by VC++ and GCC, because by default both compiler elide the copy ctor even turn off the optimize.

The gcc option -fno-elide-constructors is valuable for me to observe  the exact semantics without any optimization. And the fact of the "copy ctor must be available" is also very helpful.

Comment: Richard Corden said "VC is broken in this regard", according to my test of VC2010, only in the following regard:

struct F
{
 F(int i) { puts("F(int)"); }
 ~F() { puts("~F() "); }
 private: F(const F & other) { puts("F(const F &)"); }
};
F f = 3;
In this case, VC2010 will compile OK even there's a private copy ctor. But gcc will properly spit out error message as:
error: 'F::F(const F&)' is private

For the case:
F f = F(3);
Both VC2010 and gcc can detect there's a private copy ctor and refuse to compile

Answer (score 8):

The second one may or may not call for an extra `myclass` object construction if copy elision is not implemented by your compiler. However, most constructors, have copy elision turned on by default even without any optimization switch.

**Note** initialization while construction never ever calls the assignment operator.

Always, keep in mind:

> **assignment:**      an already present object gets a new value
>
> **initialization:**  a new object gets a value at the moment it is born.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with NRVO whatsoever.

Comment: I meant the elision, couldn't come up with the right term at the time. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In the second one, a temporary object is created first and then is copied into the object x using myClass's copy constructor. Hence both are not the same.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the following to try and <strike>illustrate</strike> understand what's going on:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(int x)
    {
        this -> x = x;
        cout << "int constructor called with value x = " << x << endl;
    }

    myClass(const myClass& mc)
    {
        cout << "copy constructor called with value = " << mc.x << endl;
        x = mc.x;
    }

    myClass & operator = (const myClass & that)
    {
        cout << "assignment called" << endl;
        if(this != &that)
        {
            x = that.x;
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    myClass x(3);
    myClass y = myClass(3);
}
```

When I compile and run this code I get the following output:

```
$ ./a.out
int constructor called with value x = 3
int constructor called with value x = 3
```

This would **seem** to indicate that there is no difference between the two calls made in the main function, but that would be wrong.  As [litb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587070/c-constructor-syntax/587116#587116) pointed out, the copy constructor *must* be available for this code to work, even though it gets elided in this case.  To prove that, just move the copy constructor in the code above to the private section of the class definition.  You should see the following error:

```
$ g++ myClass.cpp 
myClass.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
myClass.cpp:27: error: ‘myClass::myClass(const myClass&)’ is private
myClass.cpp:37: error: within this context
```

Also note that the assignment operator is *never* called.

Comment: But if I remove the copy constructor from that code entirely, it still works. What does that imply?

Comment: That implies that your compiler is inserting a default copy constructor for you.