# Is there a difference between copy-initialization and direct-initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization, copy-initialization, direct-initialization

Suppose I have this function:

```
void my_test()
{
    A a1 = A_factory_func();
    A a2(A_factory_func());

    double b1 = 0.5;
    double b2(0.5);

    A c1;
    A c2 = A();
    A c3(A());
}
```

In each grouping, are these statements identical? Or is there an extra (possibly optimizable) copy in some of the initializations?

I have seen people say both things. Please **cite** text as proof. Also add other cases please.

Comment: And there is the fourth case discussed by @JohannesSchaub - `A c1; A c2 = c1; A c3(c1);`.

Comment: _Just a 2018 note:_ The rules have changed in **C++17**, see, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154264/what-changes-to-c-made-copy-initialization-work-for-class-with-explicit-constr). If my understanding is correct, in C++17, both statements are effectively the same (even if the copy ctor is explicit). Moreover, if the init expression would be of other type than `A`, copy initialization would not require existence of copy/move constuctor. This is why `std::atomic<int> a = 1;` is ok in C++17 but not before.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

### C++17 Update

In C++17, the meaning of `A_factory_func()` changed from creating a temporary object (C++<=14) to just specifying the initialization of whatever object this expression is initialized to (loosely speaking) in C++17. These objects (called "result objects") are the variables created by a declaration (like `a1`), artificial objects created when the initialization ends up being discarded, or if an object is needed for reference binding (like, in `A_factory_func();`. In the last case, an object is artificially created, called "temporary materialization", because `A_factory_func()` doesn't have a variable or reference that otherwise would require an object to exist).

As examples in our case, in the case of `a1` and `a2` special rules say that in such declarations, the result object of a prvalue initializer of the same type as `a1` is variable `a1`, and therefore `A_factory_func()` directly initializes the object `a1`. Any intermediary functional-style cast would not have any effect, because `A_factory_func(another-prvalue)` just "passes through" the result object of the outer prvalue to be also the result object of the inner prvalue.

---

```
A a1 = A_factory_func();
A a2(A_factory_func());
```

Depends on what type `A_factory_func()` returns. I assume it returns an `A` - then it's doing the same - except that when the copy constructor is explicit, then the first one will fail. Read [8.6/14](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#14)

```
double b1 = 0.5;
double b2(0.5);
```

This is doing the same because it's a built-in type (this means not a class type here). Read [8.6/14](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#14).

```
A c1;
A c2 = A();
A c3(A());
```

This is not doing the same. The first default-initializes if `A` is a non-POD, and doesn't do any initialization for a POD (Read [8.6/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#9)). The second copy initializes: Value-initializes a temporary and then copies that value into `c2` (Read [5.2.3/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#2) and [8.6/14](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#14)). This of course will require a non-explicit copy constructor (Read [8.6/14](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#14) and [12.3.1/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.ctor#3) and [13.3.1.3/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ctor#1) ). The third creates a function declaration for a function `c3` that returns an `A` and that takes a function pointer to a function returning a `A` (Read [8.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ambig.res)).

---

**Delving into Initializations** Direct and Copy initialization

While they look identical and are supposed to do the same, these two forms are remarkably different in certain cases. The two forms of initialization are direct and copy initialization:

```
T t(x);
T t = x;
```

There is behavior we can attribute to each of them:

- Direct initialization behaves like a function call to an overloaded function: The functions, in this case, are the constructors of `T` (including `explicit` ones), and the argument is `x`. Overload resolution will find the best matching constructor, and when needed will do any implicit conversion required.
- Copy initialization constructs an implicit conversion sequence: It tries to convert `x` to an object of type `T`. (It then may copy over that object into the to-initialized object, so a copy constructor is needed too - but this is not important below)

As you see, *copy initialization* is in some way a part of direct initialization with regard to possible implicit conversions: While direct initialization has all constructors available to call, and *in addition* can do any implicit conversion it needs to match up argument types, copy initialization can just set up one implicit conversion sequence.

I tried hard and [got the following code to output different text for each of those forms](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/708ae8b380c63ba8), without using the "obvious" through `explicit` constructors.

```
#include <iostream>
struct B;
struct A { 
  operator B();
};

struct B { 
  B() { }
  B(A const&) { std::cout << "<direct> "; }
};

A::operator B() { std::cout << "<copy> "; return B(); }

int main() { 
  A a;
  B b1(a);  // 1)
  B b2 = a; // 2)
}
// output: <direct> <copy>
```

How does it work, and why does it output that result?

1. **Direct initialization**

   It first doesn't know anything about conversion. It will just try to call a constructor. In this case, the following constructor is available and is an *exact match*:

   ```
    B(A const&)
   ```

   There is no conversion, much less a user defined conversion, needed to call that constructor (note that no const qualification conversion happens here either). And so direct initialization will call it.
2. **Copy initialization**

   As said above, copy initialization will construct a conversion sequence when `a` has not type `B` or derived from it (which is clearly the case here). So it will look for ways to do the conversion, and will find the following candidates

   ```
    B(A const&)
    operator B(A&);
   ```

   Notice how I rewrote the conversion function: The parameter type reflects the type of the `this` pointer, which in a non-const member function is to non-const. Now, we call these candidates with `x` as argument. The winner is the conversion function: Because if we have two candidate functions both accepting a reference to the same type, then the *less const* version wins (this is, by the way, also the mechanism that prefers non-const member function calls for non-const objects).

   Note that if we change the conversion function to be a const member function, then the conversion is ambiguous (because both have a parameter type of `A const&` then): The Comeau compiler rejects it properly, but GCC accepts it in non-pedantic mode. Switching to `-pedantic` makes it output the proper ambiguity warning too, though.

Comment: Wow. I didn't even realize about the function declaration. I pretty much have to accept your answer just for being the only one to know about that.

Is there a reason that function declarations work that way? It would be better if c3 were treated differently inside a function.

Comment: Bah, sorry folks, but i had to remove my comment and post it again, because of the new formatting engine: It's because in function parameters, `R() == R(*)()` and `T[] == T*` . That is, function types are function pointer types, and array types are pointer-to-element types. This sucks. It can be worked-around by `A c3((A()));` (parens around the expression).

Comment: I tried your example and it outputs <direct> <direct>. Does it depend on compiler?(I'm using VS2010). Or has it changed in C++0x?

Comment: May I ask what "'Read 8.5/14'" means? What does that refer to? A book? A chapter? A website?

Comment: @AzP many folks on SO often want references to the C++ spec, and that's what I did here, in response to rlbond's request "Please cite text as proof.". I don't want to cite the spec, since that bloats my answer and is a lot more work to keep up to date (redundancy).

Comment: Thanks, great references, I just didn't understand it was the spec you were referring to. Perhaps add a note on that in the beginning?

Comment: Is it safe to say that when doing `B b1(a)`, then conversions of A to B are not considered, and a matching constructor overload must exist? Or is it a matter of priority (i.e. Matching constructor overload tried first, then conversion attempted)?

Comment: so if `A c3(A())` declares a function named c3 that returns an A and takes a function type A() (or better, its corresponding function pointer type), how could I ever construct an object using direct initialization from an unnamed temporary object?? like :
`type name(type());` ?? this code is calling the copy-constructor isn't it?

Comment: @luca i recomend to start a new question for that so others can benefit from the answer people give aswell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468557/temporary-objects-and-copy-constructor
ok, I posted,please have a look :)

Comment: Can someone explain why `A a2(A_factory_func())` is NOT interpreted as a function declaration?

Comment: @neil.tesseracted what type would `A_factory_func` be? As the name says, it's a function.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb  Forgive me if I'm being a noob but the first paragraph says `A a1 = A_factory_func();` and `A a2(A_factory_func());` are doing the same thing. So why is `A a2(A_factory_func());` doing initialization instead of function declaration?

Comment: @neil.tesseracted I don't understand why it should declare a function. What would the function take as parameter? It's not as in my example `A c3(A());` where function `c3` takes a function pointer to a function that returns `A`. But your hypothetical function `a2` would take a function pointer to a function returning.. Dunno. Therefore it isn't a function declaration: C++ parsers are sensitive to whether something is a type or not.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Sorry but I still don't get it. Isn't `A_factory_func()` returning an `A`? so function `a2` is taking a function pointer to a function that returns an `A`, right?

Comment: @neil.tesseracted no that is not why some declarations are treated as function declarations. I recommend that you open a new question, quoting my comments and your comments. It's better answered there, since it seems to require some more elaborated explanations.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Can you please please please... help me with your statements in the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35962647/confusion-in-copy-initialization-and-direct-initialization ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Just a note about the very first point made in this answer--the copy may be [elided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision), so while the variables `a1` and `a2` will effectively contain copies of the variable returned from `A_factory_func()`, `A`'s copy constructor itself may not always actually get called.

Comment: _Direct initialization behaves like a function call to an overloaded function_. Why ? Relating to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) **overload_resolution** is performed if we have more then one _candidate function_. But in most cases we have just one matching constructor for a class....

Comment: @goulashsoup for some cases, overload resolution is always done. Direct initialization is such a case. Direct function calls are only submitted to overload resolution "if the postfix-expression denotes a set of overloaded functions and/or function templates". This is a point where the spec isn't really self-consistent though.. somewhere else it says "Of interest in [over.call.func] are only those function calls in which the postfix-expression ultimately contains a name that denotes one or more functions that might be called.".. this however is not a contradiction.

Comment: Since C++17 no copy constructor is required for the first case

Comment: @M.M updated. I couldn't find a difference regarding both cases in C++17, so both cases are no-copy in C++17, i suppose. I seem to remember there was some difference, but I couldn't spot it in the draft. So I'd be glad if you could review my changes.

Comment: "*The second copy initializes: Value-initializes a temporary and then copies that value into `c2`*" - wouldn't that mean it will call one default c'tor and one move/copy c'tor?

Comment: You wrote: “*The second copy initializes: Value-initializes a temporary and then copies that value into c2 (Read 5.2.3/2 and 8.6/14). This of course will require a non-explicit copy constructor (Read 8.6/14 and 12.3.1/3 and 13.3.1.3/1 ).*” What about the case when I have an explicit copy ctor and a matching assignment operator? Should work as well, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 59):

**Assignment** is different from **initialization**.

Both of the following lines do *initialization*. A single constructor call is done:

```
A a1 = A_factory_func();  // calls copy constructor
A a1(A_factory_func());   // calls copy constructor
```

but it's not equivalent to:

```
A a1;                     // calls default constructor
a1 = A_factory_func();    // (assignment) calls operator =
```

I don't have a text at the moment to prove this but it's very easy to experiment:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() { 
        cout << "default constructor" << endl;
    }

    A(const A& x) { 
        cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
    }

    const A& operator = (const A& x) {
        cout << "operator =" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;       // default constructor
    A b(a);    // copy constructor
    A c = a;   // copy constructor
    c = b;     // operator =
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good reference: "The C++ Programming Language, Special Edition" by Bjarne Stroustrup, section 10.4.4.1 (page 245). Describes copy initialization and copy assignment and why they are fundamentally different (though they both use the = operator as syntax).

Comment: Minor nit, but I really don't like when people say that "A a( x )" and "A a = x" are equal.  Strictly they're not.  In lots of cases they will do exactly the same thing but it is possible to create examples where depending on the argument different constructors are actually called.

Comment: I'm not talking about "syntactic equivalence." Semantically, both ways of *initialization* are the same.

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari In Johannes's answer's code you get different output based on which of the two you use.

Comment: @BrianGordon Yeah, you're right. They are not equivalent. I had addressed Richard's comment in my edit long ago.

Comment: init need ADD resource , while, assigment means you should RELEASE the orignal resouce and take a copy or move the right side's object's resouce to you.

Answer (score 40):

`double b1 = 0.5;` is implicit call of constructor.

`double b2(0.5);` is explicit call.

Look at the following code to see the difference:

```
#include <iostream>
class sss { 
public: 
  explicit sss( int ) 
  { 
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
  };
  sss( double ) 
  {
    std::cout << "double" << std::endl;
  };
};

int main() 
{ 
  sss ddd( 7 ); // calls int constructor 
  sss xxx = 7;  // calls double constructor 
  return 0;
}
```

If your class has no explicit constuctors than explicit and implicit calls are identical.

Comment: +1. Nice answer. Good to also note the explicit version. By the way, it's important to note that you can't have *both* versions of a single constructor overload at the same time. So, it would just fail to compile in the explicit case. If they both compile, they have to behave similarly.

Comment: That must be the accepted answer! Short and clear example.

Comment: why does `sss x = 7` invoke the double ctor though given `7` being an `int`?

Comment: @xyf I think this happens because "copy initialisation" just can't use explicit constructors at all, even if the type of data matches. Therefore, it selects the only other available constructor that it can implicitly convert to. In this case `int` is implicitly converted to `double`. Copy-paste this code into online compiler, and remove the `explicit` keyword from `sss(int)`. In both cases `int` constructor will be called, as expected.

Answer (score 8):

You can see its difference in `explicit` and `implicit` constructor types when you initialize an object :

**Classes :**

```
class A
{
    A(int) { }      // converting constructor
    A(int, int) { } // converting constructor (C++11)
};

class B
{
    explicit B(int) { }
    explicit B(int, int) { }
};
```

**And in the** `main` **function :**

```
int main()
{
    A a1 = 1;      // OK: copy-initialization selects A::A(int)
    A a2(2);       // OK: direct-initialization selects A::A(int)
    A a3 {4, 5};   // OK: direct-list-initialization selects A::A(int, int)
    A a4 = {4, 5}; // OK: copy-list-initialization selects A::A(int, int)
    A a5 = (A)1;   // OK: explicit cast performs static_cast

//  B b1 = 1;      // error: copy-initialization does not consider B::B(int)
    B b2(2);       // OK: direct-initialization selects B::B(int)
    B b3 {4, 5};   // OK: direct-list-initialization selects B::B(int, int)
//  B b4 = {4, 5}; // error: copy-list-initialization does not consider B::B(int,int)
    B b5 = (B)1;   // OK: explicit cast performs static_cast
}
```

By default, a constructor is as `implicit` so you have two way to initialize it :

```
A a1 = 1;        // this is copy initialization
A a2(2);         // this is direct initialization
```

And by defining a structure as `explicit` just you have one way as direct :

```
B b2(2);        // this is direct initialization
B b5 = (B)1;    // not problem if you either use of assign to initialize and cast it as static_cast
```

Answer (score 6):

Of note:

[12.2/1] `Temporaries of class type are created in various contexts: ... and in some initializations (8.5).`

I.e., for copy-initialization.

[12.8/15] `When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy construction of a class object ...`

In other words, a good compiler will *not* create a copy for copy-initialization when it can be avoided; instead it will just call the constructor directly -- ie, just like for direct-initialization.

In other words, copy-initialization is just like direct-initialization in most cases <opinion> where understandable code has been written.  Since direct-initialization potentially causes arbitrary (and therefore probably unknown) conversions, I prefer to always use copy-initialization when possible.  (With the bonus that it actually looks like initialization.)</opinion>

Technical goriness:
[12.2/1 cont from above] `Even when the creation of the temporary object is avoided (12.8), all the semantic restrictions must be respected as if the temporary object was created.`

Glad I'm not writing a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 4):

First grouping: it depends on what `A_factory_func` returns. The first line is an example of *copy initialization*, the second line is *direct initialization*. If `A_factory_func` returns an `A` object then they are equivalent, they both call the copy constructor for `A`, otherwise the first version creates an rvalue of type `A` from an available conversion operators for the return type of `A_factory_func` or appropriate `A` constructors, and then calls the copy constructor to construct `a1` from this temporary. The second version attempts to find a suitable constructor that takes whatever `A_factory_func` returns, or that takes something that the return value can be implicitly converted to.

Second grouping: exactly the same logic holds, except that built in types don't have any exotic constructors so they are, in practice, identical.

Third grouping: `c1` is default initialized, `c2` is copy-initialized from a value initialized temporary. Any members of `c1` that have pod-type (or members of members, etc., etc.) may not be initialized if the user supplied default constructors (if any) do not explicitly initialize them. For `c2`, it depends on whether there is a user supplied copy constructor and whether that appropriately initializes those members, but the members of the temporary will all be initialized (zero-initialized if not otherwise explicitly initialized). As litb spotted, `c3` is a trap. It's actually a function declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Answering with respect to this part:

> A c2 = A(); A c3(A());

Since most of the answers are pre-c++11 I am adding what c++11 has to say about this:

> A simple-type-specifier (7.1.6.2) or typename-specifier (14.6)
>   followed by a parenthesized expression-list constructs a value of the
>   specified type given the expression list. If the expression list is a
>   single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in
>   definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast
>   expression (5.4). If the type specified is a class type, the class
>   type shall be complete. **If the expression list specifies more than a
>   single value, the type shall be a class with a suitably declared
>   constructor (8.5, 12.1), and the expression T(x1, x2, ...) is
>   equivalent in effect to the declaration T t(x1, x2, ...);** for some
>   invented temporary variable t, with the result being the value of t as
>   a prvalue.

So optimization or not they are equivalent as per the standard.
Note that this is in accordance with what other answers have mentioned. Just quoting what the standard has to say for sake of correctness.

Comment: Neither of your examples' "expression list specifies more than a single value". How is any of this relevant?

Answer (score 2):

This is from C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup:

An initialization with an = is considered a *copy initialization*. In principle, a copy of the initializer (the object we are copying from) is placed into the initialized object. However, such a copy may be optimized away (elided), and a move operation (based on move semantics) may be used if the initializer is an rvalue. Leaving out the = makes the initialization explicit. Explicit initialization is known as *direct initialization*.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these cases are subject to an object's implementation so it's hard to give you a concrete answer.

Consider the case

```
A a = 5;
A a(5);
```

In this case assuming a proper assignment operator & initializing constructor which accept a single integer argument, how I implement said methods affects the behavior of each line. It is common practice however for one of those to call the other in the implementation as to eliminate duplicate code (although in a case as simple as this there would be no real purpose.)

Edit: As mentioned in other responses, the first line will in fact call the copy constructor. Consider the comments relating to the assignment operator as behavior pertaining to a stand alone assignment.

That said, how the compiler optimizes the code will then have it's own impact. If I have the initializing constructor calling the "=" operator - if the compiler makes no optimizations, the top line would then perform 2 jumps as opposed to one in the bottom line.

Now, for the most common situations, your compiler will optimize through these cases and eliminate this type of inefficiencies. So effectively all the different situations you describe will turn out the same. If you want to see exactly what is being done, you can look at the object code or an assembly output of your compiler.

Comment: It's not an *optimization*. The compiler *has to* call the constructor alike in both cases. As a result, none of them will compile if you just have `operator =(const int)` and no `A(const int)`. See @jia3ep's answer for more details.

Comment: I believe you're correct actually. However it will compile just fine by using a default copy constructor.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned, it is common practice to have a copy constructor call an assignment operator, at which point compiler optimizations do come into play.