# When is "this" pointer initialized in C++?

Tags: c++

Hi I have a question about `this` pointer, when an object is constructed, when it is initialized? Which means, when can I use it? The virtual table is constructed in the constructor, is the same with `this` pointer?

For example, I have a code like this. The output is 8. Does it mean that before the constructor is entered, `this` pointer is already initialized?

```
class A{
   public:
     A() { cout<<sizeof(*this);}
     int i;
     int *p; 
};

int main() {      
    A a; 
}
```

If it is true, what else would happen before the constructor is entered ?

If it is not true, when is the `this` pointer initialized ?

Comment: The compiler knows the size of *this, it generates a hardcoded value.  Maybe you need a better example.

Comment: sizeof is a compile-time thing (I wouldn't say hardcoded) and is not dependent on the value contained in the "this" pointer at runtime. Also, the vtable (should there be one) is not constructed "in the constructor".

Comment: to Neil: really? if not int the constructor, what's that?

Comment: See my answer below.  The vtable is known and built at compile time, and loaded at run time.  The instance-vptr to the vtable is assigned just before the constructor is called.  The assignment is done by compiler-generated infrastructure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `this` pointer isn't a member of the object or class - it's an implicit parameter to the method that you call. As such it's passed in much like any other parameter - except that you don't directly ask for it.

In your example above, the constructor is a special method, which is in turn a special kind of function. When you construct the object, the compiler allocates memory for it (in this case on the stack, as `a` is a local variable in the `main` function. Then it automatically calls the constructor to initialise the object.

As part of calling the constructor, the implicit parameter `this` - a pointer to your object - is passed in as a parameter.

In a method with the following signature...

```
void MyMethod (const int* p) const;
```

there are actually two parameters, both pointers. There's the explicit parameter `p` and the implicit parameter `this`. The `const` at the end of the line specifies that `this` is a const pointer, much as the earlier one specifies that `p` is a const pointer. The need for that special syntax only exists because `this` is passed implicitly, so you can't specify const-ness in the normal way as with other parameters.

A "static" method doesn't have the implicit "this" parameter, and cannot directly access the object members either - there may not be a particular object associated with the call. It is basically a standard function rather than a method, except with access to private members (providing it can find an object to access).

As Steve Fallows points out, `sizeof (this)` is known at compile-time, because it is a pointer type and all pointers (*1) have the same `sizeof` value. The "8" you see implies you are compiling for a 64-bit platform. `this` is usable at this point - it points to valid memory, and all the members have completed their constructor calls. However, it isn't necessarily fully initialised - you are still in the constructor call after all.

**EDIT**

*1 - strictly, that may not be true - but the compiler knows what type of pointer it's dealing with here even though the value isn't known until runtime.

Comment: +1, nice explanation. `this` in context of calling conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 7):

The `this` pointer is not stored. When the constructor is called for an object that occupies a specific memory location, that location is passed as a parameter to the constructor and other member functions.

If `this` would be stored inside the object, how to retrieve that pointer? Right, you would again need the `this` pointer :)

Comment: Just to add some explanation in case it's needed - when you access a member of an object inside a method, the compiler uses `this` behind the scenes to find the object and member. `member1` and `this->member1` are really the same thing - the first form is just a shorthand.

Comment: +1 for your last statement sending me into an infinite recursion

Answer (score 2):

sizeof(*this) is known at compile time. So the cout statement reveals nothing about the initialization of this.

Given that the constructor can immediately begin accessing members of the object, clearly this is initialized before the constructor begins.

What else happens before the constructor? Well could be anything. I don't think the standard limits what a compiler *could* do. Maybe you should specify anything you're thinking might happen.

Answer (score 2):

> *The virtual table is constructed in the constructor, is the same with this pointer?*

The virtual table is NOT constructed in the constructor.
Typically, a single global v-table is shared by all instances of the same class, and each individual class has its own global v-table.
The v-table is known at compile-time, and "constructed" at program load time.

The `this` pointer is "constructed" (I think "allocated" is a better term) at allocation time, that is, after the [global `new` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t48aek43%28VS.71%29.aspx) is called, and before the constructor is entered.

In cases where the object is stack-allocated instead of heap-allocated, global `new` is not called, but `this` is still available as a result of allocating stack-space, which is just before the constructor is entered.

The instance `vptr` is assigned after the object's memory is allocated, and just before the constructor is called.

Comment: The vtable is not constructed there, but the pointer to the vtable (vptr) still needs to be filled in.

Comment: edited to mention the assignment of vptr, which happens after allocation, and before construction.

Comment: And all this assumes that there is a vtable - a compiler may implement run-time dispatch any way it wants, so long as it achieves the expected result. That may possibly mean modifying some kind of data structure with every call at run-time (perhaps to make the most common calls run faster) - though I am talking "in theory" here rather than "in reality", since it's hard to beat a vtable for efficiency.

Comment: `this` is a parameter to each and every (non-static) method. It is never 'constructed' nor 'allocated'. Creating an object first allocates a large enough block of memory and pass a pointer into it to the most derived type constructor. Note that while in the first case `this` is a pointer into the beginning of the allocated memory block, whenever there is multiple inheritance, `this` may not be a pointer to the beginning of the allocated memory: `struct b1 { int x; b1(); }; struct b2 { int x; b2(); }; struct d : b1, b2 {}` the `this` pointer passed to the `b1` and `b2` constructors differ.

Comment: That is, in some cases `this` will coincide with the allocated pointer, and in some other cases it won't. `this` does not need to be the result of the allocation even if in many cases it will coincide.

Comment: @abelenky: it's forbidden to call pure virtual functions in ctor/dtor. i'm guessing that's because vptr is not-yet/yet-not redirected to derived class. am i wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean that before the constructor is entered, the `this` pointer is already initialized?

**Yes**, the value of the `this` pointer is **known** before the constructor is even called.  This value is available via the `this` keyword inside constructors, constructor [initialization lists](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html), destructors, member methods.  The `this` keyword behaves on the surface as a method variable (of pointer type) but is not one; it typically sits in a register (`ecx` on x86 platforms) and you typically won't be able to compile code like `&this`.

> What else would happen before the constructor is entered

At least as far as the `this` pointer is concerned, the first thing that happens (unless using [placement `new`](http://www.glenmccl.com/nd_cmp.htm)) is the **allocation of memory** ultimately pointed to by `this`, be it on the stack (like in your example) or on the heap (using `new`.)  At this point the `this` pointer is known.  Then, either **default constructors or explicitly specified constructors** (via constructor initialization lists) **are then called** on the base classes (if any) and on your class non-[POD](http://www.fnal.gov/docs/working-groups/fpcltf/Pkg/ISOcxx/doc/POD.html) member variables (if any).  The class `vtable` pointer is also set before this point if your class contains virtual methods or destructor.  Then, your class constructor body, if any, is invoked.  (Constructor are called recursively, i.e. when a base class' constructor is called, the latter's base class constructors are called followed by non-POD member constructors, with the base class' `vtable` pointer being set, followed by the class' constructor body.)

Answer (score 0):

The this pointer is the first argument to every call of the class, including the constructor.

When a class method is called, the address of the class is pushed onto the stack last (assuming cdecl calling convention here). This is read back into a register to use as the this pointer.

Constructors are in fact called as if they were ordinary member functions.

You cannot have a virtual constructor because the constructor is responsible for setting the vtable member.

Comment: Some, or all, of the above may be true for your specific compiler, but none of what you say is specified by the C++ Standard.

Answer (score 0):

As nobugz already pointed out, your example doesn't really mean much -- `sizeof` yields its results based on the *type* of the object you pass to it. It does *not* evaluate its operand at run-time.

That said, yes, `this` is initialized before entry to the ctor. Basically, the compiler allocates space for the object (on the stack if the object has automatic storage duration, or using `::operator new` if it has dynamic storage duration). Upon entry to the ctor, the ctors for base classes (if any) have already run to completion. When your ctor is called, `this` gives the address of the memory that was allocated for the object.

Answer (score 0):

**this** starts pointing to the current object and all members and base classes have been initialized before you enter the constructor body.

Therefore, you can hand out pointer to **this** in the initialization list, but the receiver should do nothing else other than storing it, because the pointed-at instance may not be fully constructed at the time.

```
#include <iostream>

class B;

class A
{
    B* b_ptr;
public:
    A(B* b);
};

class B
{
    A a;
    int i;
public:
    B(): a(this), i(10) {}
    void foo() const { std::cout << "My value is " << i << '\n'; }
};

A::A(B* b):
    b_ptr(b) //Ok to store
{
    b_ptr->foo(); //not OK to use, will access initialized member
}

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```