# Declare reference to class as class member

Tags: c++, class, object, reference

I want to declare a reference to class as similar to pointer to class as its own member variable. Following is the code I have written, but I am now stuck how to proceed further to create object of such a class, since the compiler will always give error even if I wrote default constructor or constructor to initialize only `var`.

```
class Test2
{
private:
    Test2& testRef;
    int var;

public:
    Test2( int x, Test2 testObj ) : var( x ), testRef( testObj )
    {

    }
};
```

What I need to do further to create object of such class or is simply not possible to do so. If not possible why not the compilers simply gives an error saying **you can't have reference to the own class**.

Comment: @wonkorealtime that is not required here I deliberately don't want any optimizations.

Comment: I think you need to reconsider the structure of your project because having reference to your class inside that class may cause some issues in your further development...

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg I just want to know whether it is possible to do or not if yes/no then why yes/no.

Comment: this is not about optimisations, but have a look here: http://cpp.sh/9b2c . What you want it to always initialize the contained reference.

Comment: I think from the syntactic point of view there is no contraindications, however you will need to threat the reference differently in case of testRef will be set by `Test2( int x, Test2& testObj )` and differently when you will set the reference from your default constructor...

Comment: You are trying to store a reference to local variable `testObj`. This cannot end well.

Comment: The lifetime of `testObj` only last during the constructor so it will be destroyed when the ctor finishes. Changing that to `Test2&` will be fine and I guess your question reduces to "where comes the first object". It turns out there're many ways you can tweak, e.g., reinterpret an arbitrary pointer as Test2*. @wonkorealtime gave more sound solutions above. So the compiler won't stop you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a reference member, you have to initialize it in all constructors, because a reference must be initialized. Even your default constructor. Since the first object of such a class you create will not have anything else it can refer to, you will have to refer it to itself. For example:

```
Test2() :testRef(*this) {}
```

Comment: is that legal to do in C++

Comment: I think your answer is the only possible way with which I can create the first  object of such a class with or without assigning other member variables.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza: As far as I am aware, yes, it is legal. I've never seen anything to the contrary, and I can't get any compiler to complain about it.

Comment: One more question on the usage of `Test2() :testRef(*this)` how come here using `this` was valid even when the object is not fully constructed yet.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza: Not sure how to answer that other than stating the obvious. Because the language allows it. Why *shouldn't* `this` be valid? By the time the constructor starts, the address of the object is known, so why shouldn't that information be available to the programmer?

Comment: @Krishna_Oza SO maybe comes to rescue: [when-is-this-pointer-initialized-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483679/when-is-this-pointer-initialized-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You try to pass a temporary copy of your object to the reference. 
If you pass the reference in the constructor, it will be ok :

```
Test2( int x, Test2& testObj ) : var( x ), testRef( testObj )
{

}
```

Additional question : do you need your reference non const ?
It's probably better to use a const reference to your object if you don't modify it :

```
class Test2
{
  private:
    const Test2& testRef;
  public:
    Test2( int x, const Test2& testObj ) : var(x), testRef(testObj) {}
};
```

private:
    Test2& testRef;
    int var;

public:
    Test2( int x, Test2 testObj ) : var( x ), testRef( testObj )
    {

```
}
```

};

Moreover, you should initialize in the same order than declared :

```
Test2(int x, const Test2& testObj) : testRef(testObj), var(x) {}
```

Comment: the question here is how in the first place the object which is passed as reference `Test2& testObj` got created.

Comment: Ho! That's right. Then consider my answer only as a remark.

Comment: @MikeSeymour  **as long as it exists before you pass it to the constructor** that's what I want to know how to even create that first object.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza: Sorry, I didn't notice that the reference is to the same type. Ignore my (deleted) comment. I guess the first object would have to refer to itself, since you've made it mandatory to refer to something and there's nothing else to refer to.