# no matching function call for QAbstractItemModel derived class

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting this error :

```
/MyApp/company.cpp:3: error: no matching function for call to ‘DepList::DepList(Company*, Company*)’
 Company::Company(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent),dep_cache(this,this),search_results(this,this)
                                                                                                  ^
/MyApp/company.h:14: In file included from ../../../../MyApp/company.h:14:0,
/MyApp/company.cpp:1: from ../../../../MyApp/company.cpp:1:
/MyApp/deplist.h:34: candidate: DepList::DepList(QAbstractItemModel*, Company*)
     explicit DepList(QAbstractItemModel *parent = 0,Company* p_company=0);
/MyApp/deplist.h:34: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Company*’ to ‘QAbstractItemModel*’
              ^
```

when compiling the `constructor` code for `Company` class:

```
Company::Company(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent),dep_cache(this,this),search_results(this,this)
{
    // .... some intialization stuff here, unrelated to the error
}
```

and it only happens with classes where the parent is `QAbstractItemModel`. With other classes , parents of `QObject` I am using *initialization lists* without errors. The error appeared when I added initialization lists.

this is how `search_results` is declared inside Company class:

```
class Company : public QObject {
    ...
    DepList             search_results;
    ...
}
```

and it's constructor is:

```
DepList::DepList(QAbstractItemModel *parent,Company* p_company) : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{
    company=p_company;
}
```

What is the problem here , and why it only happens with `QAbstractItemModel`?? `QAbstractItemModel` is also a child of `QObject` and I have no problems with initialization lists in `QObject` classes. I had a thought of casting , but would it be safe ?

`Company` is a `QObject`-derived:

```
class Company : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
    explicit            Company(QObject *parent = 0);
    ...
};
```

But `DepList` is a `QAbstractItemModel`-derived:

```
class DepList : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    ...
    explicit DepList(QAbstractItemModel *parent = 0,Company* p_company=0);
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is, as the error message said, `Company*` can't convert to `QAbstractItemModel*`. `Company` seems has nothing to do with `QAbstractItemModel`, isn't it?

Comment: @songyuanyao you are correct, it is not. But its member `search_results` is a subclass of QAbstractItemModel. And both are inheriting `QObject`. I am initializing `search_results` inside the constructor of the `Company` object

Comment: I know you're initializing `search_results` by `search_results(this,this)`, which is calling the constructor of `DepList`, which expects the 1st argument is a `QAbstractItemModel *`; but you're passing `this`, i.e. `Company*`. Then what do you expect the compiler to do?

Comment: As an aside, passing in the `this` pointer of an object which is not fully constructed is a bit dangerous. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483679/when-is-this-pointer-initialized-in-c and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dddwwd.aspx for more details.

Comment: @songyuanyao, but I am passing `this` (i.e. the Company object) to the `search_results` member because to create itself, it needs 2 parameters, the parent (which is the Company itself) and the Company (yes, it is duplicated, but only in this particular case, in any other case parent might not be Company object). Basically I want to call constructors of the Company class members by hand. Why with other classes it does compile and in this case it doesn't? I have done the same with other classes already

Comment: The parent must be `QAbstractItemModel` but `Company` isn't. If you change `Company` to inherit from `QAbstractItemModel` instead of `QObject` then it will work fine.

Comment: @songyuanyao but Company should not be a model at all. Company can have a lot of models as it's members. So, I can not make this change. There has to be another way. Otherwise I will have to construct objects as pointers.

Comment: @songyuanyao, I have made another example, maybe you could understand it better? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663093/creating-qabstractitemmodel-object-from-constructor

Comment: @songyuanyao, I found the error. My constructor for the `DepList` class receives `QAbstractItemModel` class as a parent object. This is wrong. It should receive a `QObject` object.