# Strange assignment problem - C++

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

Having a strange problem making a new string class and assigning an array of `char*` to it in the GCC compiler. Source code:

```
#include "../Include/StdString.h"

StdString::StdString()
{
    //ctor
    internstr = std::string();
}

char* StdString::operator=(StdString other) {
    return other.cstr();
}

StdString StdString::operator+(StdString other) {
    StdString newstr = StdString();
    newstr.internstr = internstr+other.internstr;
    return newstr;
}

void StdString::operator=(char* other) {
    internstr = other;
}

StdString::~StdString()
{
    //dtor
}

char* StdString::cstr() {
    return (char*)internstr.c_str();
}
```

Error: conversion from `char*` to non-scalar type `StdString` requested.

How did `std::string` do their assignments?

Comment: Happens when I set StdString mystr = "Hello world!";

Comment: Please consider posting a minimal working example here.

Comment: why are you using pastebin?  The code will fit here.

Comment: Code wasn't pasting right from my IDE like it usually would (indents were incorrect), so I thought it would be quicker to use pastebin

Comment: Did you get the error on this method: void StdString::operator=(char* other) ? I feel strange on this operator overloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::string can do its conversion because it defines a [conversion constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384007/conversion-constructor-vs-conversion-operator-precedence).  Something like this.

```
class std::string {
  // ...
std::string(const char *);
};
```

NOTE: the actual std::string is more complicated.

With the assignment operator you should be able to do

```
StdString str;
str = "hello";
```

but not

```
StdString str = "hello";
```

Comment: If `StdString` is more like `std::string`, then the initialization must also work. `std::string` has a overloaded constructor having argument type `const char*`. [Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

Comment: Thanks! This turned out to be the solution

Answer (score 1):

The error you're having is for not providing a constructor that takes a `char*`. This is the conversion function the compiler complains about for being missing.

```
StdString::StdString(char const* s)
{
    // ...
}
```

Also, if your internal string is a `std::string` then you don't need any of the assignment operators, copy constructor and destructor. Once you add the `char*` conversion constructor the compiler-provided assignment operator will magically work for `char*` as well. Well, not really magically: the compiler will see that it can convert a `char *` to a `StdString` through your conversion constructor, and then use that with the implicit assignment operator.

You can also leave the default constructor's definition empty; this will give you the default construction for all members, which is probably good enough.

Answer (score 1):

> StdString mystr = "Hello world!";

requires copy constructor.

Try to add the following:

```
StdString::StdString(const char* other)
{
    internstr = other;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are confusing assignment and initialization.  Initialization uses a constructor, even when it's called with a "=" symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you define your conversion operator as:

```
char* StdString::operator=(StdString other) 
{ 
    return other.cstr(); 
}
```

All this does return the contents of `other` without setting the current class's `internstr` to that given by other.

What I would do would look more like:

```
StdString& StdString::operator=(StdString other) 
{ 
    //  copy contents of other to this->internstr

    return *this;
}
```