# C++11: Ambiguity between Converting Constructor and Conversion Function in Initialization of Pass-By-Value Parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, implicit-conversion, language-lawyer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Y;

struct X
{
    X(const Y&) { cout << "converting constructor" << endl; }
};

struct Y
{
    operator X() { cout << "conversion function" << endl; }
};

void f(X x) {}

int main()
{
    Y y;
    f(y);
}
```

In the above the **conversion function** is given priority to the **converting constructor** by my compiler (gcc 4.6.1), however in the standard it states that:

> User-defined conversions are applied only where they are unambiguous

It would seem that there is ambiguity in this case.  Can anyone explain the contradiction?

I would have expected the above to not compile.  I'm also pretty sure years ago that Scott Meyers wrote about this specific example and said that it wouldn't compile.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because X constructor wants a `const` argument, it prefers the operator. If you remove the `const` in the X constructor then compiler complains about ambiguity. If there are more than one functions with reference parameters, the one with the most relaxed const qualification is preferred.

A good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1384044/390913)

Answer (score 1):

There is no ambiguity here, the only valid conversion is provided by the **conversion function**.
Note that `y`is **not a `const`**, your **conversion constructor** needs a `const` argument.

There would be a ambiguity, If your conversion constructor took a non const reference.

**[Online Sample:](http://ideone.com/maf3y)**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Y;

struct X
{
    X(Y&) { cout << "converting constructor" << endl; }

};

struct Y
{
    operator X() { cout << "conversion function" << endl; }
};

void f(X x) {}

int main()
{
    Y y;
    f(y);
    return 0;  
}
```

**Output:**

> prog.cpp: In member function ‘Y::operator X()’:
>   prog.cpp:13: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
>   prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   prog.cpp:21: error: conversion from ‘Y’ to ‘X’ is ambiguous
>   prog.cpp:13: note: candidates are: Y::operator X()
>   prog.cpp:8: note:                 X::X(Y&)

Comment: Btw, there is nothing c++11 specific in the code sample.The code is valid even in c++03.

Comment: What is the reason for Downvoting this? Please specify reasons when you downvote to indicate what you feel is wrong and if you cannot think of any logical/technical reasons for justifying the downvote, please consider yourself not qualified for downvoting.

Comment: i am sorry. i thought that the reason i downvoted it is already given in the accepted answer. the constructor *can* be used by the conversion. but it is not preferred.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Yes it *Can* be used but there is **no ambiguity** here, the order in which the const or non const versions will be selected is well defined.Not sure If my choice of words seems to indicate anything otherwise in the answer.