# Is this user-defined conversion not ambiguous? If so, what rule allows it?

Tags: c++, c++11

> `[C++11: 12.3/2]:` User-defined conversions are applied only where they are unambiguous. [..]

Yet, the following [compiles just fine in GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6191a6016d6a3ddf) and Clang trunk:

```
struct B;
struct A
{
    A();
    operator B();
};

struct B
{
    B(const A&);
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    (B)a;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: (question spawned from http://stackoverflow.com/q/22444415/560648)

Comment: @PawełStawarz: Those are linker errors. It _compiled_ just fine. Add the `-c` switch if it makes you feel better :)

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661078/c11-ambiguity-between-converting-constructor-and-conversion-function-in-initi?rq=1

Comment: @jpw: Ah, yes, could be

Comment: And following that link, the answer here seems to explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384007/conversion-constructor-vs-conversion-operator-precedence/1384044#1384044

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what's the error message from Clang?

Comment: @billz: You mean, the other compiler in which there is no error message? ;P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cast notation `(B)a` is equivalent in this case to `static_cast<B>(a)` (§5.4/4). This in turn has the same semantics as the initialization `B t(a)`, where `t` is a temporary (§5.2.9/4). Since `B` has class type, and the initialization is a direct-initialization, only the constructors of `B` are considered (§8.5/16). The applicable constructors are:

- converting constructor `B::B(const A&)`
- implicitly defined copy constructor `B::B(const B&)`
- implicitly defined move constructor `B::B(B&&)`

The converting constructor wins overload resolution since the implicit conversion from `A` to `const A&` is an exact match.