# I thought static_cast<TYPE>() was equivalent to TYPE(variable) in C++?

Tags: c++, casting

I just came across something I don't quite understand. I thought that `static_cast<TYPE>(variable)` was equivalent (or better/safer) than `TYPE(variable)`. However, the following code DOES not work

```
HMENU hMenu = CreateMenu();
HMENU hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();

// File
AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, WndClass_main::ID_FILE_EXIT, "&Quit");
AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, static_cast<intptr_t>(hSubMenu), "&File");
```

My compiler says that it can't convert from `HMENU` to `intptr_t`. I have a 64-bit system btw, which interfers with the casting between `void*` and `int`? However, from what I understand the type `intptr_t` (defined in cstdint) is guaranteed to be big enough for a `void*`.

The interesting part is that the following (note the different cast) works:

```
HMENU hMenu = CreateMenu();
HMENU hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();

// File
AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, WndClass_main::ID_FILE_EXIT, "&Quit");
AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (intptr_t)(hSubMenu), "&File");
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the different between a `static_cast` and a `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: C's cast syntax is `(TYPE)variable` -- or, more precisely, `(` *`type-name`* `)` *`cast-expression`*. The `TYPE(variable)` syntax is specific to C++.

Comment: It is indeed better/safer than function-style or C-style casts, in that it doesn't allow dodgy conversions like this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought that `static_cast<TYPE>(variable)` was equivalent (or better/safer) than `TYPE(variable)`.

It's just a subset. Some conversions can be performed by both, but some can only be performed by the latter. For function-style casts the standard specifies in [expr.type.conv]:

> If the expression list is a single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast expression (5.4).

That is, `TYPE(variable)` is equivalent to `(TYPE)variable`. Now for the latter the standard specifies

> The conversions performed by
>
> - a `const_cast` (5.2.11),
> - a `static_cast` (5.2.9),
> - a `static_cast` followed by a const_cast,
> - a `reinterpret_cast` (5.2.10), or
> - a `reinterpret_cast` followed by a `const_cast`,
>
> can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion.

<sub>(Note that there is an additional text explaining some differences concerning class hierarchies, which is not quite relevant here.)</sub>
In your case, `static_cast` does not suffice. `reinterpret_cast` would, since it can convert integers to pointers and vice versa. One of the reasons why `reinterpret_cast` should then be preferred is e.g. the ability of being found by a search for potentially dangerous casts. For further queries on when to use both, see [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used).

Comment: And that is, of course, assuming that `TYPE` in `TYPE(variable)` is a primitive type and not a class with a constructor.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone What is "that"? If you mean the equivalency of the casts: Not really. Why would we have to make that assumption?

Comment: @MarkRansom What can I say? Everything tells me you're wrong, including [**this code snippet**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac0cdb1ca5ba0468).

Comment: Interesting. I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384007/conversion-constructor-vs-conversion-operator-precedence) which asks which will be called, but when I edit your test snippet to make the type conversion operator `const` it doesn't change the result as the answer suggests it should. Either way I'm deleting my earlier comment because it's clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It is safer.  It is also weaker.  It is safer, because it is weaker.

A `static_cast` will do implicit casting, plus it will cast a pointer *down* a class hierarchy.

It will also cast a pointer to/from `void*` with the same `const` `volatile` qualifications.  (from I believe is implicit in C -- it is not in C++).

These are the "safer" set of casts in C/C++.

`const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` gets the more dangerous ones.  These include converting a pointer value to an integer, even if the integer is big enough.

My advice is to write this function:

```
intptr_t ptr_to_intptr( void* p ) { return reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(p); }
```

which makes the operation clear, then use it.

Unlike `(intptr_t)` it will only work on pointers -- so if you accidentally fed it something that isn't a pointer.  Or a pointer you cannot store in an `intptr_t` like a pointer-to-member.