# static_cast Conversion constructor vs Conversion operator

Tags: c++, gcc, casting, static-cast

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384007/conversion-constructor-vs-conversion-operator-precedence) I tried making such conversion with `static_cast`:

```
class A;

class B { 
      public: 
         B(){} 

         B(const A&) //conversion constructor
         { 
              cout << "called B's conversion constructor" << endl; 
         } 
};

class A { 
      public: 
         operator B() const //conversion operator
         { 
              cout << "called A's conversion operator" << endl; 
              return B(); 
         } 
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    //Original code, This is ambiguous, 
    //because both operator and constructor have same cv qualification (use -pedantic flag)
    B b = a;

    //Why isn't this ambiguous, Why is conversion constructor called, 
    //if both constructor and  operator have same c-v qualification
    B c = static_cast<B>(a); 
    return 0;
}
```

I expected it to not compile, because both constructor and operator have same *c-v qualification*. However it compiled, successfully and `static_cast` calls constructor instead of operator. Why?

(compiled using gcc 4.8.1 with `pedantic` and `Wall` flags)

Answer (score 8):

The C++11 Standard says (emphasis mine):

> **5.2.9 Static cast**
>
> 4 Otherwise, an expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` **if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed**, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5). The effect of such an explicit conversion is the same as performing the declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion. The expression `e` is used as a glvalue if and only if the initialization uses it as a glvalue.
>
> 5 Otherwise, the `static_cast` shall perform one of the conversions listed below. No other conversion shall be performed explicitly using a `static_cast`.

That explains why the `static_cast` in

```
B c = static_cast<B>(a);
```

ends up calling the constructor of `B`.

The conversion operator is used only if the `T t(e)` is not well-formed.

Comment: I understand that this sentence means that if `B temporary(a)` is valid `static_cast` can be preformed, but I don't see there why constructor takes precedence.

Comment: @PcAF, I couldn't find a clause that says the `static_cast` can be performed using the conversion operator. However, if there is one, it is given lower precedence than the above.

Comment: @R Sahu Remove `B(const A&)` conversion constructor and now `static_cast` works with conversion operator.

Comment: @PcAF, the conversion operator is given lower precedence. See the updated answer.

Comment: @R Sahu Your answer makes sense and is correct. And do you have reference in standard for that? Because in sentence you highlighted I don't see anything about precedence.

Comment: @PcAF, the "Otherwise" in the start of the clauses implies precedence.