# Allowing the use of two variable types seamlessly

Tags: c++, templates

I am in a situation where I have to produce C++ code that is going to be used from the JNI. I have defined along with the java peers the right structure to pass data. However there is a legacy, hacky and super ugly structure that I was asked to use instead of the clean structure designed. So I have something like:

```
struct NiceStructure{
    int a;
    int b;
    bool c;
};


struct LegacyStructure{
    string a;
    double b;
    bool c;
    int old_dont_use;
    string type;
    int I_dont_remember_what_this_is_but_dont_touch_it;
    bool clip;
};
```

The `NiceStructure` is well suited for the operations I want to perform and the `LegacyStructure` can be hacked (like it has traditionally been) to do what I want to do.

The question is: **Can I program a type agnostic function that can deal with both structures?**

An example function would be:

```
vector<NiceStructure> do_something(vector<NiceStructure> array_of_values){      
    vector<NiceStructure> res;
    for (int i=0; i< array_of_values.size(); i++){
        if (array_of_values[i].a + array_of_values[i].b > 10 && array_of_values[i].c)
            res.push_back(array_of_values[i])
    }
    return res;
}
```

I should be able to change the type `NiceStructure` by `LegacyStructure` and work with either of them somehow.

Comment: Or build a conversion constructor for NiceStructure out of LegacyStructure or conversion operator in LegacyStructure for NiceStructure and make your methods accept NiceStructure. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384007/conversion-constructor-vs-conversion-operator-precedence

Comment: I agree with the conversion. Actually it was my first option. However since the amount of structures is in the hundreds of thousands, I might not want to "waste" time in conversions. At least I was told so...

Comment: Would it be an option to make the legacy structures a private aggregate member of the new ones?

Comment: Could you please post an example of what you mean?

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera `struct NiceStructure{private: LegacyStructure data;};`  and your NiceStructure can operate directly on the data of the legacy structure...

Comment: hummm, don't really like it but it could be a way

Comment: or make a member function that outputs a LegacyStructure from NiceStructure: LegacyStructure NiceStructure::GetLegacyStructure(). Then you only make one when needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, I would try to avoid writing code that works with both data types. Instead write converters to and from the Legacy format and quarantine `LegacyStructure` type as early as possible.

for example:

```
// Updates the LegacyStructure in place.
// This is our quarantine point.
void updateLegacy(LegacyStructure & s) {
  NiceStructure n = fromLegacy(s);
  updateNice(n);
  syncLegacy(s, n);
}

// The brains is here, and its free from Legacy cruft
void updateNice(NiceStructure &n) { ... }

// We need a way to get back all the changed fields from
// a NiceStructure back into a LegacyStrcuture
void syncLegacy(LegacyStructure &s, const NiceStructure & n);

// And a way to get our initial NiceStructure
NiceStructure fromLegacy(const LegacyStructure & s);
```

If end up needing to avoid copies of the data (For example you're working on a vector`<LegacyStructure>`), then there are a few options. I think the neatest of these is to actually use templates, but to do it through
a traits type approach, to access each field as a common type.

```
// Base trait type - 
// Trying to use this on any type we haven't specialised on 
// will cause an error
template<typename T>
struct StructureTraits {};

// Specialisation of traits type for LegacyStructure
template<>
struct StructureTraits<LegacyStructure> {
  static int getA(const LegacyStructure &s) { return int_from_string(s.a); }
  static void setA(LegacyStructrue &s, int a) { s.a = string_from_int(s); }
  ...
};

// Specialisation of traits type for NiceStructure
template<>
struct StructureTraits<NiceStructure> {
   static int getA(const NiceStructure &s) { return s.a; }
   static void setA(LegacyStructure &s, int a) { s.a. = a; }
};

//TODO: Need some template hackery to provide const versions etc.

// This version will work for both types. 
template<typename T>
void updateStructureList( std::vector<T> & structures ) { 
  for( auto & x : structures ) {
     StructureTraits<T>::setA(x, StructureTraits<T>::getA(x) + 1 );
  }
}
```

Alternative approaches include, adding a common base type to both classes or creating an interface with simple wrappers for both classes.

Comment: That's going to be quite a lot of copying if you have a vector of `LegacyStructure`.

Comment: @MartinBonner agreed. I'd still go with doing the copy until profiling shows that it is a bottleneck. But I've added an alternative traits based approach for when you really need to avoid those copies.

Comment: "Write clean code first and then optimize IF the profiler says you have a problem" - Hey!  That's *my* line.  (Lots of copying is an "obvious" bottleneck.  So far I have twice managed to guess where the performance problem is; but I've only been doing this 35 years. I did once reject a very simple architecture because it would be too slow.  We eventually switched to it because the other approach was too complex; it turned out not to be too slow.)