# 2 simple variable initialization question

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializatio)

Is there any difference between,

```
int x(5);
int x = 5;
```

& What's the difference between,

```
int const x(5);
const int x(5);
```

Comment: Cause I want to know for both perspective.

Comment: If the question was just the first part, then the down vote is probably ok. But, if you follow the answers regarding the 2nd part of the question, then *this down vote is wrong.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really good rule of thumb regarding `const`:

> **Read Declarations Right-to-Left.**

(see Vandevoorde/Josutiss "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide")

E.g.:

```
int const x; // x is a constant int
const int x; // x is an int which is const

// easy. the rule becomes really useful in the following:
int const * const p; // p is const-pointer to const-int
int const &p;        // p is a reference to const-int
int * const * p;     // p is a pointer to const-pointer to int.
```

Ever since I follow this rule-of-thumb, I never misinterpreted such declarations again.

(: sisab retcarahc-rep a no ton ,sisab nekot-rep a no tfel-ot-thgir naem I hguohT :tidE

Comment: @iamcreasy: there's a typo in your comment.

Comment: @martinho-fernandes `Read Right-to-Left.`

Comment: @iamcreasy. I did. There's a typo in there. And now it's too late for you to fix it :P

Comment: ah, :| can't edit the post now! :P let is slide this time.

Answer (score 4):

Of the 4 lines you show, only 1 is valid C.

```
int x(5);        /* INVALID C */
int x = 5;
int const x(5);  /* INVALID C */
const int x(5);  /* INVALID C */
```

I don't know the meaning of the invalid lines in other languages. In C, the meaning of the valid line is to create an object with name `x`, type `int`, and value `5`.

---

To define a "const" (better: a "read-only") object, the C syntax is

```
const int x = 5;
int const x = 5;
```

but `x` cannot be used in places where only constants are allowed. `x` is not a constant: it is an **object** of type `const int`

```
#define CONSTANT 42
enum /*unnamed*/ { First=1, Second, Third };
switch (var) {
    case x: break; /* invalid use of x; only constants allowed in case labels */
    case 15: break; /* ok; 15 is a constant */
    case CONSTANT: break; /* ok; CONSTANT is a constant with value 42 */
    case Second: break; /* ok; Second is a constant with value 2 */
}
```

Comment: is, `const int x = 5` valid in C?

Comment: Yes, it creates an object named `x`, with value `5` and qualified type `const int`. Note the (unqualified or base) type is still `int`; it doesn't create a constant (as usuable in, for instance, case labels): it creates an object that cannot be changed through that identifier.

Comment: to make use of `case x: break;` do I have to use `const int x = 5;` ?

Comment: @iamcreasy: no, in C the type qualifier `const` does not create a constant. It creates an object that cannot have its value changed through its defining name. **Objects** cannot be used where **constants** are expected. Use one of the other options when you need a real constant.

Answer (score 2):

For the first, there's no difference for built-in types.  For class types, the `T x = y` notation requires a copy constructor, the `T x(y)` notation doesn't. **EDIT**: Also, as one of the commenters pointed out, `T x = y` will not work if the `T(y)` constructor is declared `explicit`.

For the second, there's no difference as far as the compiler is concerned, but the second (`const int`) can lead to confusion in many cases, especially when `typedef`s are involved, e.g.:

```
typedef int* IntPtr;
IntPtr const cpi1;  //  Const pointer to a non-const int.
const IntPtr cpi2;  //  Also a const pointer to a non-const int.
```

In both definitions, the `const` applies to the pointer.

Because of this confusion, it's generally considered better practice to put the `const` after what it modifies.  Now—for a long time, putting the `const` at the start was usual, with the result that the practice is widespread.

Comment: `const` at the start is also how it's usually written in the standard.

Comment: "For class types, the `T x = y` notation requires a copy constructor, the `T x(y)` notation doesn't." This is not so. Both require a copy constructor. `T x = y` looks like assignment but is not one.

Comment: @Fernandes Yes, and the standard is based on the ARM.  It never seemed worth the bother changing (and there are some older programmers who are so used to `const int` they wouldn't feel comfortable if we did change).  The "generally accepted" best practice has changed to favor `int const`, but not to the point where you'd be criticized for using `const int`, or where it would be worth changing the practice in existing code.

Comment: @Rafal `T x(y)` does not require a copy constructor.  It requires a constructor which can be invoked with whatever type `y` has.  `T x = y` requires an accessible copy constructor.  (And nobody said anything about assignment.)

Comment: @James It's good to know about this recommendation. I think I'll be more careful in the future :) Also, you may want to mention that T x = y; will not work if a call to an explicit constructor would be involved.

Comment: @James: You are correct, I typed my comment before realizing that y need not be the same type as x.

Comment: @Martinho Good point concerning the explicit constructor.  That's likely to affect as much code as the need for a copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

No both are exactly same until you are using an **Argument**. It's just a matter of coding style.

[Note: But Following are not same:

```
int x;  // x is variable
int x();  // x is function declaration
```

]

Comment: This is a better answer because it raises a useful warning.

Answer (score 1):

About the `const` keyword:

- It makes const what is immediately to its *left*
- If there is nothing to the left, then it applies to the *right*.

So, `int const i` and `const int i` are the same.

But, `int *const i` and `const int *i` are not the same: in the first expression, the pointer is constant, in the second expression, the integer pointed to is constant. Als `int const* i` is equivalent to the second one.

Comment: * character, which side does it work first? Left or right?

Comment: `*` either follows a **type name**: in this case it is a type modifier (modifies the type to a pointer type), or follows an **expression**: in this case it is the multiplication operator, or precedes an expression that is bound to a pointer type: it is the **dereference** operator. There is no such rule.

Comment: `int *const i` : i is a const pointer, which point a non-const int & `int const* i` : i is a pointer which, points to an const int. It is correct?

Comment: @iamcreasy: yes. That's what many people tell here!

Answer (score 0):

No difference. Alternate ways to initialize the variable to a value.

But did you try this on your system? What did you get?

Comment: I tried and they were the same. I thought some technical details might lurk behind.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in c++, in c, however - `int x(5);` is not allowed

Answer (score -1):

```
int x(5);
int x = 5;
```

No difference.

```
int const x(5);
const int x(5);
```

No difference.

```
int x = 5;
const int *p = &x;
int *const q = &x;
```

Here is a difference in `p` and `q`. Using `p` you can't change the value of `x`, but you can assign a new address to `p`. Using `q`, you cannot point to any other memory location, but you can modify `x` using `q`.

Comment: There's no difference in your third example.

Comment: @martinho fernandes: fixed. thanks. :)

Comment: -1 The final paragraph is simply wrong.

Comment: @james kanze: wrong after edit? what's wrong?

Comment: It was wrong when I read it and commented.  The important thing is that `int const` and `const int` are identical in meaning.  Regardless of what follows.