# const char* and char const* - are they the same?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

From my understanding, `const` modifiers should be read from right to left. From that, I get that:

```
const char*
```

is a pointer whose char elements can't be modified, but the pointer itself can, and

```
char const*
```

is a constant pointer to `mutable` chars.

But I get the following errors for the following code:

```
const char* x = new char[20];
x = new char[30];   //this works, as expected
x[0] = 'a';         //gives an error as expected

char const* y = new char[20];
y = new char[20];   //this works, although the pointer should be const (right?)
y[0] = 'a';         //this doesn't although I expect it to work
```

So... which one is it? Is my understanding or my compiler(VS 2005) wrong?

Comment: When in doubt always use the [Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: *"...whose char elements can be modified, but the pointer itself can, and..."* — I think you meant to say "can't" for one of those "can"s, but I don't know how confused you are so I don't know which to correct :P

Comment: Try this website: www.cdecl.org

Comment: Compiler is never wrong ;)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Actually, according to the standard, `const` modifies the element directly to *its left*. The use of `const` at the beginning of a declaration is just a convenient mental shortcut.  So the following two statements are equivalent:

```
char const * pointerToConstantContent1;
const char * pointerToConstantContent2;
```

In order to ensure the pointer itself is not modified, `const` should be placed after the asterisk:

```
char * const constantPointerToMutableContent;
```

To protect both the pointer and the content to which it points, use two consts.

```
char const * const constantPointerToConstantContent;
```

I've personally adopted *always* putting the const after the portion I intend not to modify such that I maintain consistency even when the pointer is the part I wish to keep constant.

Comment: 'convenient shorthand' is an interesting description for something which is not shorter and doesn't follow the normal rules.

Comment: The standard doesn't really care which order you use. Section 7.1.6 just shows both places and says use it in only one.

Comment: @beetstra I agree. I changed it to "convenient mental shortcut" to be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 32):

It works because both are same. May be you confused in this,

```
const char*  // both are same
char const*
```

and

```
char* const  // unmutable pointer to "char"
```

and

```
const char* const  // unmutable pointer to "const char"
```

[To remember this, here is a simple rule, **'*' affects its whole LHS first**]

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `unmutable pointer to char*`.It is a unmutable pointer pointing to `char` not `char *`.

Answer (score 28):

That is because the rule is:

RULE: `const` binds left, unless there is nothing on the left, then it binds right :)

so, look at these as:

```
(const --->> char)*
(char <<--- const)*
```

both same! oh, and `--->>` and `<<---` are NOT operators, they just show what the `const` binds to.

Comment: yeah, correct operator is `-->>` and it operates only on values. Try `int i = 8; std::cout << (i -->> 1) << std::endl;` :)

Answer (score 13):

(from [2 simple variable initialization question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580324/2-simple-variable-initialization-question))

A really good rule of thumb regarding `const`:

> **Read Declarations Right-to-Left.**

(see Vandevoorde/Josutiss "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide")

E.g.:

```
int const x; // x is a constant int
const int x; // x is an int which is const

// easy. the rule becomes really useful in the following:
int const * const p; // p is const-pointer to const-int
int const &p;        // p is a reference to const-int
int * const * p;     // p is a pointer to const-pointer to int.
```

Ever since I follow this rule-of-thumb, I never misinterpreted such declarations again.

(: sisab retcarahc-rep a no ton ,sisab nekot-rep a no tfel-ot-thgir naem I hguohT :tidE

Comment: +1 This is fantastic, thank you! I've been trying to get my head around things like `const char* const` for ages and thanks to you I now get it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I always try to interpret:

`char *p`

```
     |_____ start from the asterisk. The above declaration is read as: "content of `p` is a `char`".
```

`char * const p`

```
     |_____ again start from the asterisk. "content of constant (since we have the `const` 
            modifier in the front) `p` is a `char`".
```

`char const *p`

```
           |_____ again start from the asterisk. "content of `p` is a constant `char`".
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In both of your cases you're pointing to a constant char.

```
const char * x  //(1) a variable pointer to a constant char
char const * x  //(2) a variable pointer to a constant char
char * const x  //(3) a constant pointer to a variable char
char const * const x //(4) a constant pointer to a constant char
char const * const * x //(5) a variable pointer to a constant pointer to a constant char
char const * const * const x //(6) can you guess this one?
```

By default, `const` applies to what is inmediately at is left, but it could apply to what is inmediately at its right if there's nothing preceeding it, as in (1).

Comment: Last one: A constant variable pointer, to a constant pointer, to a constant char.

Comment: If by "constant variable pointer" you mean "constant pointer", then you nailed it bro!

Comment: Well in (5) that's a variable pointer to a constant pointer to a constant char  simply because there's no "const" to the right of the last asterisk before the identifier "x".  But in (6) that becomes a constant pointer, the rest remaining the same.