# what is the difference between char* const and const char*?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I am very confused with `char* const` and `const char*`.

```
char str[100];
```

When `str` decays into `pointer`, it become `char* const` or `const char*`

Comment: It seems your question has been answered [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091770/const-char-and-char-const-are-they-the-same)

Answer (score 3):

```
char* const
```

Declares a **constant pointer**.

```
const char*
```

Declares a **pointer** to **constant data.**

`str` decays to a **pointer**. (as [self.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2327831/self) "pointed")

Comment: Not sure about the decay. I would say it decays just to a `char*` pointer.