# const specifier for pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I can declare `foo(const T& var)` so that I know var won't be changed.

Equivalent format for pointer would be `foo(const T* var)`?

In the past I tried those, errors related to `iterator`/`const_iterator` irritated me and I just tended to use `(T* var)` without considering constness.

Are there a good doc for declaring function that enforces contents pointed by a pointer won't change'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have is already a pointer that prohibits the pointee's contents from changing. You can see this by using the "read backwards" rule:

```
const T* var     <===== left to right from this read
```

Reading backwards:

> `var` is a pointer to a `T` that is constant

This is different from

```
T* const var
```

Which reads:

> `var` is a constant pointer to a `T`

The difference here is that the constant is `var`, not the `T`; that means you can change the `T` by dereferencing `var` but you cannot change what `var` points to.

And of course you can have both of the above at the same time:

```
const T* const var
```

Comment: @Eugene: If you could be more specific... which error? From what code?

Answer (score 0):

(from [2 simple variable initialization question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580324/2-simple-variable-initialization-question))

A really good rule of thumb regarding `const`:

> **Read Declarations Right-to-Left.**

(see Vandevoorde/Josutiss "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide")

E.g.:

```
int const x; // x is a constant int
const int x; // x is an int which is const

// easy. the rule becomes really useful in the following:
int const * const p; // p is const-pointer to const-int
int const &p;        // p is a reference to const-int
int * const * p;     // p is a pointer to const-pointer to int.
```

Ever since I follow this rule-of-thumb, I never misinterpreted such declarations again.

(: sisab retcarahc-rep a no ton ,sisab nekot-rep a no tfel-ot-thgir naem I hguohT :tidE

Equally, you can write your function signatures to this rule:

```
void foo (int const * const p)
```

now, `p` is a const-pointer to const-int. This means that inside the function's body, you cannot let `p` point to something else, i.e. you can not change the pointer, nor can you change what it is point to.

p being a const-pointer is information that is really only relevant to your function's body, and you should omit this information from the header file:

```
// foo.h
void foo (int const *p);
```

then

```
// foo.cc
void foo (int const * const p) {
    // Here, the const serves you as the implementor as an additional
    // safety gear.
}
```