# Copy initialization in constructor initializer?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Why can't my constructor initializer use copy initialization?

```
struct S { int a; S(int b) : a(b)  {} }; // direct initialization compiles
struct T { int a; T(int b) : a = b {} }; // copy initialization does not
```

I am confused because `a(b)` and `a = b` are both expressions (postfix and assignent expressions, resp.), and my C++ book [1] says that "An initializer may be any arbitrarily complex expression."

[1] Lippman, Lajoie, Moo. "C++ Primer, 4th ed." p457.

Comment: You have your terminology wrong, `a(b)` _is_ direct initialization...

Comment: Sorry I had "direct" and "copy" transposed throughout. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not direct initialization. `T a = b;` is called *copy intialization*. Direct initialization is `T a(1, 'foo', false);`, and in your constructor you would write the familiar `T(int b)  : a(b, 'foo', false) { }` to achieve this effect, as you already have in your *first* example.

By contrast, `T a;` is called *default initialization*, which you achieve by leaving a variable entirely unmentioned in the initializer list. Its effect is to call the default constructor on class types, and to perform no initialization at all on fundamental types (ditto for arrays).

By contrast again, *value initialization* can be written as `T(int b) : a() { }`. You can also use value-initialization in `new` expressions, but they're tricker in automatic declarations due to the vexing parse.

I think direct, default and value initialization are the only permissible forms of initialization in initializer lists in C++98/03, while C++11 adds various flavours of uniform initialization to the mix.

Comment: `T a;` is _default_ initialization, not direct initialization. `T a(b);` is direct initialization.

Comment: "*no initialization at all on fundamental types (ditto for arrays)*" Or any POD-type.

Comment: @ildjarn: "defined recursively for members", I suppose?

Comment: Not sure what you mean -- a type can't be a POD-type if it contains non-POD members.

Comment: Let's see. If you initialize any object, then any member which is not mentioned in the CIL will be default-initialized, is that right? So then this proceeds recursively, until you hit a fundamental type, which is either default-initialized or not. I should be able to mix this happily with non-PODs; any given constructor along the way may choose to default-initialize one of its members. Or am I going wrong somewhere with this?

Comment: @Kerrick: Thanks for correcting my mix-up between direct and copy initialization. Any intuition on why the language won't allow copy initialization? Don't a(b) and a=b have identical semantics for POD types? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati/1051468#1051468)

Comment: @nknight: What would be the point? Direct-initialization is already good enough to invoke the copy or move constructor; what else do you need? Copy-initialization is really the most dubious feature of the language that probably only exists for cosmetic reasons...

Comment: "*If you initialize any object, then any member which is not mentioned in the CIL will be default-initialized, is that right?*" Yes, right. "*So then this proceeds recursively, until you hit a fundamental type, which is either default-initialized or not.*" Until you hit a POD-type, not just a fundamental type. Default-initialization of a POD-type == no initialization, including of that POD-type's submembers.

Comment: @ildjarn: Fair enough. But that's physically indistinguishable to the POD type having an empty default constructor that default-initializes its members, isn't it? Or is there an explicit difference? If there's a difference, then I suppose that would distinguish PODs from aggregates.

Comment: A POD type cannot have any constructor (otherwise it wouldn't be a POD type), so the question doesn't make much sense. :-P

Comment: Ah: Now this is very hair-splitty, but for the sake of argument: Can I interpret that to mean that I mustn't specify a *user-defined* constructor, and thus that the object will get a default-provided, empty constructor which does nothing? Or is there an explicit statement that there is no constructor at all? It still seems to me like the two are indistinguishable, but I'm interested if there's anything specific in the standard.

Comment: There is a _trivial_ default constructor that does nothing. The standardese is in the FDIS, §12.1.

Comment: @Kerrick: I completely agree with your practical advice that direct initialization is "already good enough" in a constructor initializer list. I have not accepted an answer yet because my question seeks to uncover (a) why my example leads to a syntax error, and (b) why this syntax rule exists for C++.

Comment: Well, (a) because copy-initialization isn't allowed in the initializer list according to the standard (12.6.2.1 in C++11), and (b) is a subjective question about the design -- personally I'm all in favour of it, and I tend to understand the CIL as "the list of constructor calls to use when constructing the subobjects and members". As such I only want explicit constructor calls. Note that copy-initialization requires an accessible and *non-explicit* copy constructor!

Comment: @nknight : The latter is not a question answerable on SO, as we don't know the language designers' intents. The best you can be told here is the correct syntax to use, which Kerrek has already done.

Comment: @ildjarn: Now I remember why I went into this extended discussion of ours: I was wondering whether I could simply remove the notion of POD entirely for the purpose of initialization and replace it by existing rules. Just a silly game for finding a minimal set of axioms, if you like -- of course knowing about PODs is very useful in practice!

Comment: @Kerrek : I'm not sure what you mean -- the existing rules are oriented around POD or non-PODness, so how could one remove the notion of POD entirely? If you mean to say that POD types will be treated as fundamental types in regards to they way they're default-initialized, then that's true, but only because it's backwards -- fundamental (scalar) types are POD types.

Comment: @ildjarn: No, rather I'd like to say that POD types are just classes with trivial constructors (for the purpose of initialization), and apply the rules recursively -- makes sense?

Comment: @Kerrek : But there's more to it than that, as always ;-] A POD type (in C++11) must have a trivial default constructor, must be trivially copyable, must not have virtual functions or virtual base classes, must have the same access control for all non-static data members, and must only contain subobjects that also meet these same criteria, etc. A class with a trivial default constructor is just that -- it takes much more than that to qualify as a POD type.

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes yes, I know... but here I mean just for the purpose of "how are members initialized": If I know that the class has a trivial constructor (and copy constructor), I already know everything I need to about the member initialization. So my question is if I still need to treat POD specially for the purpose of initialization, or can I just use the rule that "trivial constructor causes members to be default-initialized".

Comment: @Kerrek : Ah, okay, I think we're finally on the same page. :-] For your purposes (if you're using C++11 terminology) then yes, types possessing a trivial default constructor are the ones to single out in regards to default-initialization. Of course for C++03, POD-type is still the noteworthy criteria.

Comment: @ildjarn: Awesome. What's the difference in C++03 though? Does it not have "trivial constructors"? (I also didn't realize that value initialization was only added in 03; there may/will be many further gaps in my knowledge!)

Comment: @Kerrek : C++11 separated the concept of a POD-type into separate classifications: having a _trivial default constructor_, being _trivially copyable_, and being _standard layout_. In C++03 these were not separate concepts, and all three were thrown together to define 'POD-type'. (And yes, C++03's largest changes were the concept of value-initialization and requiring that `vector<>` have contiguous storage -- important changes indeed!)

Comment: @Kerrek: Thanks for the reference to the spec. It appears that the mem-initializer must use a parentheses-based initializer (direct or value, like you said). As for my subjective question (b), I was curious if you knew any deep reason for this rule, because it appears I can superficially subvert it with something perverse like `struct U { int a, b; U (int c) : a(b = c) {} };`

Comment: @nknight: No you can't: Elements are initialized in their order of declaration, and you cannot use `b` before it is initialized. Don't cheat! :-) Assignment always has to come after initialization, and in constructors never if you can help it.

Comment: @Kerreck: How come that code snippet compiles and runs without error or warning and initializes both U.a and U.b correctly (G++ 4.5.3)? Is this behavior implementation-defined?

Comment: @nknight: I'd say that's a compiler shortcoming. You're using `b` before it is initialized, since we're still in the process of initializing `a`. I'd like to ask this as a separate question; shall I do it or do you want it?

Comment: Thank you both for your insightful discussions and for patiently answering my first SO question! :)

Comment: @nknight : In C++11, you can use brace-based initializers in addition to parenthesis-based initializers. This C++11 addition is generally referred to as 'Uniform Initialization'.

Comment: @ildjarn: yay for uniform initialization! It's a great, awesome new feature (hello static constant maps!), as well as an ongoing source of GCC internal compiler errors :-)