# Initializing members out of order - is this OK?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

From a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002085/copy-initialization-in-constructor-initializer/8002122#8002122):

Class members are initialized in their order of declaration. By this logic, the following constructor should invoke undefined behaviour:

```
struct Foo
{
   Bar a;
   Bar b;

   Foo(Bar c) : a(b = c) { }
};
```

Patently, we are assigning to `b` first before `a` has been initialized. Assigning to an uninitialized object should be UB. It's not surprising that the code "works" with `Bar = int`, but if I make `Bar` a heavy class with constructors, I see that `b` does indeed get initialized before `a`.

(For extra lunacy, we can even say `Foo(Bar c, Bar d) : a(b = c), b(d) { }`, still with no warning.)

Yet GCC 4.6.1 doesn't warn about this. Is this acceptable, well-defined behaviour, or is this strictly wrong?

Comment: I believe that the reason for UB is the hardness of detection of such situations. You can dereference NULL's as well, you can't expect a compiler to give you warnings and errors on any mistake that you make with your code. Sometimes a common sense is needed.

Comment: I don't believe it's defined.  Assume `Bar` has a non-trivial constructor; clearly, `b.operator=()` is being called before `b` is constructed.  But I do not know for certain.

Comment: Is `b` getting initialized before `a`, or is it simply being assigned to before `a`?

Comment: I believe if you're trying to test compiler too much that's even for some undefined expressions, you're at problem. Not every compiler perfect about giving warning or same implementation across

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a `Bar` where non-initialized state actually matters to the assignment operator, I get warnings from GCC:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Bar {
    int n;
    Bar(int v) : n(v) {
            std::cout << "Bar " << n << " constructed\n";
    }
    Bar& operator=(const Bar& other) {
        std::cout << "Bar " << n << " assigned from " << other.n << "\n";
        n = other.n;
        return *this;
    }
};
struct Foo
{
   Bar a;
   Bar b;

   Foo(Bar c, Bar d) : a(b = c), b(d) { }
};

int main()
{
        Foo f(Bar(1), Bar(2));
}
```

test: https://ideone.com/VDZzG

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:8:32: warning: ‘*((void*)(& f)+4).Bar::n’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
test.cc:23:13: note: ‘*((void*)(& f)+4).Bar::n’ was declared here
```

Other compilers I've tried don't seem to care, though...

Comment: Visual C++ 9.0 (2008) gives following output

Bar 2 constructed
Bar 1 constructed
Bar -858993460 assigned from 1