# C++ string declaration

Tags: c++, string

I am learning C++ from the beginning and I don't get the whole strings topic.

What is the difference between the following three codes?

1. `std::string s = std::string("foo");`
2. `std::string s = new std::string("foo");`
3. `std::string s = "foo";`

Comment: Note that you generally want to use option 4: `std::string s("foo");`

Comment: @JerryCoffin: how is that different from option 3?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: it does direct initialization instead of copy initialization. At least conceptually, #3 creates a temporary string initialized from the supplied constant, then uses the copy constructor to create `s` from that value (though, admittedly, the compiler will usually omit that, and do the equivalent of direct initialization).

Comment: Don't forget the variants that use the uniform initialization syntax from the latest standards, i.e. `std::string s{"foo"};`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
std::string s = std::string("foo");
```

This creates a temporary `std::string` object containing "foo", then assigns it to `s`. (Note that compilers may elide the temporary. The temporary elison in this case is explicitly allowed by the C++ standard.)

```
std::string s = new std::string("foo");
```

This is a compiler error. The expression `new std::string("foo")` *creates an `std::string` on the free store* and returns a pointer to an `std::string`. It then attempts to assign the returned pointer of type `std::string*` to `s` of type `std::string`. The design of the `std::string` class prevents that from happening, so the compile fails.

C++ is not Java. This is not how objects are typically created, because if you forget to `delete` the returned `std::string` object you will leak memory. One of the main benefits of using `std::string` is that it manages the underlying string buffer for you automatically, so `new`-ing it kind of defeats that purpose.

```
std::string s = "foo";
```

This is essentially the same as #1. It technically initializes a new temporary string which will contain "foo", then assigns it to `s`. Again, compilers will typically elide the temporary (and in fact pretty much all non-stupid compilers nowadays do in fact eliminate the temporary), so in practice it simply constructs a new object called `s` in place.

Specifically it invokes a converting constructor in `std::string` that accepts a `const char*` argument. In the above code, the converting constructor is required to be non-`explicit`, otherwise it's a compiler error. The converting constructor is in fact non-`explicit` for `std::string`s, so the above does compile.

This is how `std::string`s are typically initialized. When `s` goes out of scope, the `s` object will be destroyed along with the underlying string buffer. Note that the following has the same effect (and is another typical way `std::string`s are initialized), in the sense that it also produces an object called `s` containing "foo".

```
std::string s("foo");
```

However, [there's a subtle difference between `std::string s = "foo";` and `std::string s("foo");`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati), one of them being that the converting constructor can be either `explicit` or non-`explicit` in the above case.

Comment: +1 for being the answer that mentions compilers not necessarily creating a temporary in #1.

Comment: Note that #1 and #3 are equivalent as far as the language is concerned.

Comment: So `std::string("foo")` creates "foo" on the stack and `new std::string("foo")` creates foo on the heap?

Comment: @Leif Ericson: Yes. (I call the "heap" the "free store".)

Comment: @LeifEricson: basically yes. The Standard amuses itself speaking of "automatic storage" for the stack and "dynamic storage" for the heap... but no implementation I know of took advantage of a different interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string s = std::string("foo");
```

This is called copy initialization. It is functionally the same as direct initialization

```
std::string s( "foo" );
```

but the former does require that the copy constructor is available and compilers may create a temporary object but most will elide the temporary and directly construct `s` to contain `"foo"`.

---

```
std::string s = new std::string("foo");
```

This will not compile because `new` returns a pointer. To make it work you'd need the type of `s` to be a `std::string *`. Then the line dynamically allocates an `std::string` object and stores the pointer in `s`. You'll need to `delete` it once you're done using it.

---

```
std::string s = "foo";
```

This is almost the same as first. It is copy initialization but it has an added constraint. It requires that the `std::string` class contains a non-`explicit` constructor that takes a `const char *`. This allows the compiler to implicitly construct a temporary `std::string` object. After that the semantics are identical to case 1.

Answer (score 2):

1. Creates a temporary string object and copies the value to `s`
2. Does not compile, `new std::string("foo")` returns a pointer to some newly allocated memory.
   For this to work, you should declare s as a pointer to a string `std::string* s`.
3. Constructs a string from a C-string.

You should use the third option in most - if not all - cases.

Answer (score 2):

1 will create a temporary variable (right hand side), then call the assignment operator to assign the value to s

2 will create an instance of `std::string` on the heap and return a pointer to it, and will fail in the assignment because you can't assign a pointer to a non-pointer type

3 will build a std::string and initialize it from a `const char*`

Comment: "you can't assign a pointer to a non-pointer type": In your opinion then `bool s; s = new std::string("Hello, world.");` is a compile-time error? BTW that equal sign is not an assignment (for example it could be legal to write `Foo x = 12;` even when `Foo::operator=(int)` is private).

Comment: @6502: His wording is wrong, but either way it can't be assigned from a `std::string`

Comment: @MooingDuck: This answer is simply wrong on a few points: A) those are not assignments, are initializations (in C++ it's a different thing, with different rules and semantic, the assignment operator that answer talks about in 1 is *NOT* called), B) The phrase "You cannot assign a pointer to a non-pointer type" is just false ... you can assign (and also initialize) a boolean from a pointer. Point 2 has IMO a very bad wording as it looks like it's saying the code will compile and one will get a runtime error... but at least there's some doubt this is not what Fred meant.

Answer (score 1):

On the number 1, you are creating a temporary string using the constructor and then assigning it to s.
Number 2 doesn't even compile.
On number 3, you are creating a new string and then assign a value to it.