# Is "MyClass a(anotherInstance);" faster than "MyClass a = anotherInstance;"?

Tags: c++, constructor, latency

I am currently re-engineering a colleague's code. I foudn that he often uses the syntax like

```
double a(anotherDouble);  --- A
```

instead of

```
double a = anotherDouble;  --- B
```

I am wondering if his syntax faster, maybe method A can save a constructor operation?

can someone give a little bit insight here?

thanks and have a nice holiday season!

Comment: "I am currently re-engineering a colleague's code." Do you not have any real work to do?

Comment: hum, actually, it's some kind of "take over", i guess it is a real work. Don't scare me, man.

Answer (score 1):

For the inbuilt datatype `double` they both are same, theres no performance difference.

In case of custom classes.
First is **Direct Initialization** while second is called **Copy Initialization**.

Good Read:

**[Is there a difference between copy initialization and direct-initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati)**

Answer (score 1):

For a `double` (or some predefined type), that should not matter. I find `double pi=3.14;` more readable than `double pi(3.14);` but it is a matter of taste.

For a user defined  `class C`, writing `C x = C(3);` may involve a constructor for initialization and another for copying, but sometimes it is optimized by the compiler.

Comment: "*sometimes* it is optimized by the compiler" should read *always* optimized by the compiler (not a requisite in the standard, but true in all current compilers)

Comment: Except when you *disable* optimizations, eg. with `g++ -O0 -Wall`

Comment: @Basile - If you disable optimizations, you are not interested in which one is the fastest. And the answer is still - No, there is no difference.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: In particular GCC will always perform that optimization even in -O0. You need to use a special flag to disable it (`-fno-elide-constructors`)

Answer (score 1):

There is no assignment operator invoked at all in this. `A a = b;` always invokes a constructor. If `b` is of object of type `A`, copy-constructor invoked. If `b` is object of some other type `B`, then suitable constructor invoked, such as `A( const B& )`. In any circumstances, `A a(b);` and `A a = b;` will result in absolutely the same code with the same constructor called once.

The following will NOT compile, since there is no suitable constructor, even though there is suitable assignment operator and default constructor for class `TB`:

```
#include <iostream>    

class TA
{
 public:
  TA()
  {
   std::cout << "TA()" << std::endl;
  }
  TA( const TA& )
  {
   std::cout << "TA(const TA&)" << std::endl;
  }
};

class TB
{
 public:
  TB()
  {
   std::cout << "TB()" << std::endl;
  }
  TB( const TB& )
  {
   std::cout << "TB(const TB&)" << std::endl;
  }
  TB& operator=( const TA& )
  {
   std::cout << "TB& operator=( const TA& )" << std::endl;
   return ( *this );
  }

};

int main( void )
{
 TA la;
 TB lb = la;

 return ( 0 );
}
```

So the answer to your question is **"No, it's not faster, it's 100% the same"**.

Answer (score 0):

`double` is not a class to start with.
But anyway, I have never seen a compiler that generates different code for these two constructs, even with classes, they generate equivalent code, and the standard states that explicitly.

Comment: "implies that specifically"? C-:

Comment: yeah, I'm not a native speaker, slipped there. Anyway, I don't remember the exact terminology, which Als mentioned anyway, so I won't extend the answer. Thanks for the tip :)