# Getting same constants to work for floats or doubles

Tags: c++

I am enabling a large code base to alternate between single and double floating point precision via a single typedef.  At present, my code is double-oriented:

```
double foo(double input)
{
    return 1.0/input;
}
```

A naive switch to programmer-specified precision looks like this:

```
#ifdef _USE_DOUBLES
typedef double fpType;
#else
typedef float fpType;
#endif

fpType foo(fpType input)
{
    return 1.0/input;
}
```

Obviously, the "1.0" causes a compiler warning.  My best solution so far is to treat every constant thus:

```
fpType foo(fpType input)
{
    return fpType(1.0)/input;
}
```

Is there any possibility that the explicit POD constructor invocation will actually be performed at runtime, thus charging me a speed penalty just for solving compiler warnings?  I suspect not, since a compile time rewrite from "fType(CONSTANT)" to "CONSTANTf" seems trivial.  But I want to make absolutely sure.  I use VC, but I want to know about C++ compilers in general.

Also, is there a more elegant solution than mine?  The fpType() invocations get ugly when lots of constants feature in one expression:

```
fpType someVal = fpType(1.0)/(someOtherVal+fpType(0.5))*(someVal      
/fpType(7.66))*fpType(43.33);
```

I expect there are compiler-specific approaches to this problem, but I seek a compiler-agnostic one, if it exists.  Naturally, I would look to warning suppression only as a last resort, perhaps not at all.

[EDIT]
I wrote this question misunderstanding "direct initialization", which is explained at [Constructor Initialization of primitive data types in CPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843715/constructor-initialization-of-primitive-data-types-in-cpp).

Comment: "Is there any possibility that the explicit POD constructor invocation will actually be performed at runtime" - huh? no.

Comment: Which kind of warning do you get ? My g++ doesn't complain at all even with `--pedantic`.

Comment: Are you referring to fpType(1.0) when you mention "POD constructor invocation"?  If so, it's a cast, not a constructor invocation.  static_cast< fpType >( 1.0 ) would probably be a better choice.

Comment: And no, there is no run-time hit for using it.

Comment: @Andy:  Yes, that's the statement.  Are you saying that float(K) is semantic sugar for (float)K?

Comment: @hivert:  Cannot verify; I only have access to VC at the moment.

Comment: @phizla - static_cast< fpType >( K ) is the C++ way to statically cast.  It's a compile time check, and hence there is no runtime hit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast

Comment: In the case of numerical constants, I assume that a C-style cast always translates to a static_cast.

Comment: It looks like "direct initialization" was the parlance I lacked.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843715/constructor-initialization-of-primitive-data-types-in-cpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the literal constants, you could use `float` type. The conversion to `double` will happen without any compiler warnings.

```
fpType foo(fpType input)
{
    return 1.0f/input;
}
```

Comment: Cool - definitely better than what I was doing.

Answer (score 3):

You may try C++11 user defined literals:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef USE_DOUBLES
constexpr double operator"" _f (double value)
{
    return value;
}
#else
constexpr float operator"" _f (double value)
{
    return value;
}
#endif /*USE_DOUBLE*/


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << 1.2_f << endl;
}
```