# Why is copy initialization the way it is? Why require the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, copy-initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the motivation behind having copy and direct initialization behave differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223285/whats-the-motivation-behind-having-copy-and-direct-initialization-behave-differ)

And by copy initialization, I mean like so:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct(int) {}
    MyStruct(const MyStruct&) {}
};

MyStruct s = 5; // needs *both* the int and copy constructor
```

Despite programming in C++ for years, I never realized the above code required the copy constructor (thanks to jogojapan). The temporary had always been elided, and as such I never even knew it even existed (at least on a superficial level, despite it being optimized away) until it was pointed out to me.

After a decent amount of googling, I get the idea of how it works. My question is *why* is it the way it is?

Why didn't the standard make it so that the above example doesn't need the copy constructor? Is there some specific case/example that shows that requiring the copy constructor in this type of initialization is important?

Without a decent explanation of *why* things are they way they are, I just see this as an annoying artifact, but I'd rather not be ignorant if there's something important that I'm missing.

Comment: It seems that need of copy constructor is for namesake; actually it's [not called](http://ideone.com/35fjAD).

Comment: @iammilind: It need not be called is due to **Copy elision**, but the copy constructor needs to be accessible.Basically, it means that the standard *allows* copy constructor to be called and it **must** be available. The Optimization is not standardese guaranteed infact its the contrary that standard accomodates for.

Comment: @JesseGood: Thanks for that. Looks like this is pretty much a duplicate. Kind of depressing there isn't a good answer on that other question...

Comment: @Cornstalks: Actually, I think the most-upvoted answer is right: `It was designed this way because it was assumed such behaviour will be expected by the programmer` IIRC, the only reason we have `MyStruct s = 5;` syntax (using =) is because so many people are used to it.

Comment: @JesseGood: I suppose that makes sense. I think that explanation paired with the earlier explanation that `MyStruct s = 5;` is more or less converted to `MyStruct s = MyStruct(5);` in order to convert the `5` to a `MyStruct` makes sense as a reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy initialization of an object is ambiguous to direct initialization, both can be used to the same extent in order to set values equal to each other.

```
int a = 4;
int a = int(4);
int a(4);
```

all of these calls are ambiguous, they all set a equal to 4. The reason for a copy constructor in the case of an integer is convenience, imagine c++ data types without this

```
int a(foo(b,r)); //a little messy for a variable declaration
int a = foo(b,r) //ok, cleaner
```

you also might might to use an implicit and explicit copy constructor, here is an example program that uses a copy constructor explicitly to handle imaginary numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
class complexNumbers {
  double real, img;
public:
  complexNumbers() : real(0), img(0) { }
  complexNumbers(const complexNumbers& c) { real = c.real; img = c.img; }
  explicit complexNumbers( double r, double i = 0.0) { real = r; img = i; }
  friend void display(complexNumbers cx);
};
void display(complexNumbers cx){
  cout<<&quot;Real Part: &quot;<<cx.real<<&quot; Imag Part: &quot;<<cx.img<<endl;
}
int main() {
  complexNumbers one(1);
  display(one);
  complexNumbers two =2;
  display(200);
  return 0;
}
```