# C++ String\ Vector initialization

Tags: c++, initialization

I have questions about C++ initialization.

In Java: if I want a empty StringBuffer, I should use

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
```

to initialize a empty string buffer.

In C++: If I want to use a empty string, I can just declare

```
std::string str;
```

or  `std::string str = "";`

In real world projects should I always write like the second form?

How about declare an empty vectors?

```
vector<int> vec;
```

Is this OK? or should I give some null values to this vec?

Comment: This is probably better for programmers.stackexchange.com, since it's an open-ended question.  That said, in my opinion, the vector is fine for general use, use its member functions like `push_back` to add members and let it handle the rest.  As for the string, if you are going to add to an empty string I would explicitly assign it for readability, but otherwise it isn't really necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. The reason I asked about this is because a few months ago when I interviewed a job, the interviewer questioned me about why I did not initialize the empty vector, so I am curious about how to initialize that in C++.

Comment: Don't confuse it with `vector<int> *vec = new vector<int>()`, which is more or less analogous to your Java example. Here, you initialize the pointer to the location of an allocated ("newed") vector. If you only write `vector<int> vec;` that's stack-allocation which happens automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

std:string and std:vector are classes, not basic types: That mean that unlike an Integer which as a pseudo-random value at the declaration moment, string and vectors has a well defined initial value.

The default value for std::string is "".

The default content for std::vector is {}.

You may use what you prefer, but the initialization is not necessary, and even not very optimal.

Comment: Thank you so much!, so if I want zero value C++ basic types, I should always assign a value?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx

Comment: Yes, you should always initialize them unless you have a good reason not to do so.

Comment: @leemes: any reason for that? why to initialize a string to ""?

Comment: @AdrianMaire he was talking about "basic types" (or at least my response "Yes" was about them only... I could not simply answer "Yes" because of the minimum number of characters ;) )

Comment: As @leemes said, for basic types, you should always initialize them: int myvar = 0;

Answer (score 1):

1. std::string str("");
   It does a direct initialization and uses string(const char *) constructor.
2. std::string str=""; 
   It does a copy initialization.
3. std::string str;
   It creates empty string.

Option 3 is just like others and less overhead. Use it
Read more about the difference from here
[What's the motivation behind having copy and direct initialization behave differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223285/whats-the-motivation-behind-having-copy-and-direct-initialization-behave-differ)

Comment: So if I use the option 3, will it be accepted in projects?

Comment: Yes, it is the best choice.