# What is difference between copy and assigning a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, assign

What is the difference between copy and assigning a vector ?
line 2 and 4 .

```
1    vector<int> V1(5);
2    vector<int> V3(V1);
3    vector<int> V4(V1.size());   
4    V4 = V1 ;
```

Comment: Copying creates a new vector. When assigning they both already exist.

Comment: The same as for any other type with copy construction and assignment. BTW you do not need the third line.

Comment: one calls the copy constructor, the other calls the `=` operator

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11706040/238902

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: If you use a type which is expensive to construct rather than a simple `int`, then the combination of line 3&4 will be more expensive as it will default-construct a lot of elements before chucking them away in favor of the copied objects. This does not happen in line 2.

Comment: This question is very vague - the syntactical difference between the two is very clear, so you probably are asking about the semantical difference. In that case, please explain *why* you ask that question, so we can focus our answer on that. This is actually a rather complex topic.

Comment: Well, one is a construction, the other is an assignment. Apart form any practical difference regarding performance, cleanliness or whatever, there is a fundamental semantic difference between changing the value of an existing object and creating a new one. So you might want to clarify your question, stating in what difference you're interested, as in respect to what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a doxygen extract from my stl implementation for `operator=`:

```
   /* All the elements of @a x are copied, but any extra memory in
   *  @a x (for fast expansion) will not be copied.  Unlike the
   *  copy constructor, the allocator object is not copied.
   */
```

As you can see there is a difference if you use custom allocators, but in other cases the result is the same.

Comment: Answers about a specific implementation are not useful unless you know which one the OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 uses a **copy constructor**. Line 4 uses a **copy assignment**. Both create copies; the first creates a new object and the second overwrites an existing object.