# Copy constructor and default assignment operator

Tags: c++

I have made the following Car class:

```
class Car
{
private:
    int  id;
    int* data;
public:
    Car(int id, int data) : id(id) , data(new int(data)){}
    //Car(const Car& rhs) : id(rhs.id) , data(new int(*rhs.data)){}
    void print(){std::cout << id << " - " << *data << " - " << data << std::endl;}
};
```

With the following main code:

```
int main()
{
Car A(1,200);
A.print();

Car B=A;
B.print();
}
```

When I run this code I get the following output:

1 - 200 - 0x14bdc20

1 - 200 - 0x14bdc20

This is also what I expected as the default assignment operator simply copies the values of id and data.

When I comment in the copy constructor and run the same code, I get the following output:

1 - 200 - 0x71bc20

1 - 200 - 0x71c050

Hence, the data pointer of B points to a new address. I do not quite understand why this happens. I thought the default assignment operator still would only copy the values from A and the only way to solve this was to overload the assignment operator. How is it the default assignment operator seems to use the copy constructor in this case?

Comment: `Car B=A;` is **copy-initialization** and not copy-assignment.

Comment: `Car B=A` is not an assignment, it's a call to the copy constructor. It is equivalent of `Car B{ A }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy assignment operator= is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635936/copy-assignment-operator-is-not-called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider what happens in the 2 cases individually. Also, note that there is difference between initialization and assignment in C++. In particular, `Car B=A;` is **copy-initialization** and not copy-assignment.

##### Case 1

Here we consider the case where there is no user defined copy-constructor. That is, the case where you've commented the copy constructor.

```
class Car
{
private:
    int  id;
    int* data;
public:
    Car(int id, int data) : id(id) , data(new int(data)){}
    void print(){std::cout << id << " - " << *data << " - " << data << std::endl;}
};
```

In this case, the compiler **implicitly synthesizes** a *copy-constructor*. That copy constructor does **memberwise copy** of the data members. That is, it simply copies, the `id` and `data` data member from the passed argument.

This explains why you get the mentioned output. Because, they are nothing but a copy of the data members of the passed object. In particular, the data member `data`(is initialized) gets a copy of the data member `data` of the passed argument. That is, both the data members `data` of the passed argument as well as the current instance point to the same `int` object. Hence, the output is the same in this case.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the case where there is a user defined copy-constructor. That is, the case where you've commented out the copy constructor.

```
class Car
{
private:
    int  id;
    int* data;
public:
    Car(int id, int data) : id(id) , data(new int(data)){}
    Car(const Car& rhs) : id(rhs.id) , data(new int(*rhs.data)){}
    void print(){std::cout << id << " - " << *data << " - " << data << std::endl;}
};
```

In this case, the data member `data` points to the a newly created `int` object due to the expression  `data(new int(data))`. Note that this is different from the case 1 because in case 1 the data member `data` simply gets a copy of the data member `data` of the passed object. That is, in case 1, both the `data` points to the same `int`. While in case 2, the data member `data` points to a separate `int` object created due to `new int(data)`. Hence the output is different in this case.