# C++ copy costructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, copy-assignment

Im trying to get a good grasp with copy constructors & I've found this part of code.

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class A1 {
        int data;
    public:
        A1(int i = 10) :
                data(i) {
            cout << "I am constructing an A1 with: " << i << endl;
        }
        A1(const A1& a1) :
                data(a1.data) {
            cout << "I am copy constructing an A1" << endl;
        }
        ~A1() {
            cout << "I am destroying an A1 with: " << data << endl;
        }
        void change() {
            data = data * 10;
        }
    };
    class A2 {
        int data;
    public:
        A2(int i = 20) :
                data(i) {
            cout << "I am constructing an A2 with: " << i << endl;
        }
        A2(const A2& a2) :
                data(a2.data) {
            cout << "I am copy constructing an A2" << endl;
        }
        ~A2() {
            cout << "I am destroying an A2 with: " << data << endl;
        }
        void change() {
            data = data * 20;
        }
    };
    class A3 {
    public:
        A3() {
            cout << "I am constructing an A3" << endl;
        }
        A3(const A3& a3) {
            cout << "I am copy constructing an A3" << endl;
        }
        ~A3() {
            cout << "I am destroying an A3" << endl;
        }
        void change() {
            cout << "Nothing to change" << endl;
        }
    };
    class A {
        A1 a1;
        A2 a2;
        A3 a3;
    public:
        A() {
            cout << "I am constructing an A" << endl;
        }
        A(const A& a) :
                a1(a.a1) {
            cout << "I am copy constructing an A" << endl;
        }
        ~A() {
            cout << "I am destroying an A" << endl;
        }
        A& operator=(const A& a) {
            cout << "I am performing a stupid assignment between As" << endl;
            if (this != &a)
                a1 = a.a1;
            return *this;
        }
        void change() {
            a1.change();
            a2.change();
            a3.change();
        }
    };
    class BigA {
        A data1;
        A& data2;
    public:
        BigA(A& a) :
                data1(a), data2(a) {
            cout << "I just constructed a BigA" << endl;
        }
        ~BigA() {
            cout << "I am destroying a BigA" << endl;
        }
        A get(int index) {
            if (index == 1)
                return data1;
            else
                return data2;
        }
    };
        BigA volta(BigA& biga)
     //BigA& volta(BigA& biga)
            {
        cout << "Volta ta data?" << endl;
        return biga;
    }
    int main() {
        A first;
        BigA biga(first);
        volta(biga).get(2).change();
        return 0;
    }
```

However,I can't understand why I get these results.Especially,why A1 and A copy constructor are called and not constructor and I don't get at all when volta function is called(The results enclosed by ****) :

```
I am constructing an A1 with: 10
I am constructing an A2 with: 20
I am constructing an A3
I am constructing an A
I am copy constructing an A1
I am constructing an A2 with: 20
I am constructing an A3
I am copy constructing an A
I just constructed a BigA
****
Volta ta data?
I am copy constructing an A1
I am constructing an A2 with: 20
I am constructing an A3
I am copy constructing an A
I am copy constructing an A1
I am constructing an A2 with: 20
I am constructing an A3
I am copy constructing an A
Nothing to change
I am destroying an A
I am destroying an A3
I am destroying an A2 with: 400
I am destroying an A1 with: 100
I am destroying a BigA
I am destroying an A
I am destroying an A3
I am destroying an A2 with: 20
I am destroying an A1 with: 10
****
I am destroying a BigA
I am destroying an A
I am destroying an A3
I am destroying an A2 with: 20
I am destroying an A1 with: 10
I am destroying an A
I am destroying an A3
I am destroying an A2 with: 20
I am destroying an A1 with: 10
```

EDIT_AssignmentOperatorQuery : If I add this function in BigA

```
void change() {
    A& rdata1 = data1;
    A cdata2 = data2;
}
```

and call it from main : `biga.change();` Why instead of the default assignment operator , the copy-constructor and constructor is being called and I get

```
I am copy constructing an A1
I am constructing an A2 with: 20
I am constructing an A3
I am copy constructing an A
```

EDIT_AnsweringMyOwnQuery : I just found out that this is initialization by copy constructor and not assignment by assignment operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with it.

### `A first;`

You create A object, its fields (non-static members) are initialized

> "[***Before the compound statement that forms the function body of the
>   constructor begins executing***, initialization of all direct bases,
>   virtual bases, and ***non-static data members is finished***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)."

```
I am constructing an A1 with: 10
I am constructing an A2 with: 20
I am constructing an A3
```

And your version of constructor without parameters is being called:

```
I am constructing an A
```

When you write

### `BigA biga(first);`

one of your `BigA` constructors is invoked. It takes a reference to `A` object, so, `first` is not copied (reference is set when providing a value).

Then, member initializer lists time comes,

```
BigA(A& a) :
            data1(a), data2(a)
```

and `data1` is of type `A`, the `first` object is copied (it is referenced here as `a`)

A new `A` object is created by its own copy constructor. At first, it calles copy constructor for `A1`,

```
A(const A& a) :
a1(a.a1)

I am copy constructing an A1
```

Then, `A`'s `a2` and `a3` fields are default-initialized.

```
I am constructing an A2 with: 20
I am constructing an A3
```

The body of copy constructor for `A1` is executed then:

```
I am copy constructing an A
```

Let's return to `BigA` initialization. We spoke about `data1` initialization until now, and now the time for `A& data2`:

```
BigA(A& a) :
            data1(a), data2(a)
```

As it is reference, and the reference being passed to initialize it, it is just an assignment, no output.

`BigA` constructor (that takes `A&`) body is executed then:

```
I just constructed a BigA
```

Now, we would try to clarify what happens on

### `volta(biga).get(2).change();`

This function is being called:

```
BigA volta(BigA& biga)
{
    cout << "Volta ta data?" << endl;
    return biga;
}
```

Again, pass by reference results in no copy constructor call.

We have function body being executed:

```
"Volta ta data?"
```

The function returns unnamed object of class `BigA`, so copy constructor should be called.

You have not provided copy constructor like `BigA (const BigA & biga)`, so the **default copy constructor is being invoked**.
It does sequential member initialization of `A data1;` and then `A& data2;`

The first member is initialized by copying `data1` field of your unnamed object, thus copy constructor of `A` is being called. What it is printed here is explained above (see: *A new `A` object is created by its own copy constructor...*)

```
I am copy constructing an A1
I am constructing an A2 with: 20
I am constructing an A3
I am copy constructing an A
```

Then, `get` method runs with `index == 2`

```
A get(int index) {
        if (index == 1)
            return data1;
        else
            return data2; // <--- this line is executed
```

`data2` is `A&`, and the method returns `A`, this leads to `A` copy constructor execution.

```
I am copy constructing an A1
I am constructing an A2 with: 20
I am constructing an A3
I am copy constructing an A
```

At last, `change` runs

```
void change() {
        a1.change();
        a2.change();
        a3.change();
    }
```

and only `a3.change()` prints something:

```
Nothing to change
```

### On program termination

The destruction occurs in the reverse order, and the last created `change`'d object is destroyed at first.

```
I am destroying an A
I am destroying an A3
I am destroying an A2 with: 400
I am destroying an A1 with: 100
```

`I am destroying a BigA` is printed twice, but `I just constructed a BigA` - only once. The latter is due to you have no copy constructor for `BigA` that takes `const & BigA` (it is also pointed out above).

### Answering your query

```
void change() {
    A& rdata1 = data1;
    A cdata2 = data2;
}
//in the main():
biga.change();
```

Yes, you're right that the copy constructor would be called here `A cdata2 = data2;` because the object `cdata2` is previously uninitialized. This is the case well explained [under this ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11706040/1566267).

If you change the code like that

```
A cdata2;
cdata2 = data2;
```

you would see the expected assignment:

```
I am constructing an A1 with: 10
I am constructing an A2 with: 20
I am constructing an A3
I am constructing an A
I am performing a stupid assignment between As
```

Comment: Thanks for the super analytical explanation it was more that I could ask.However a problem came up (I Edited my question) with the assignment operator (or so I think) and I would be grateful if you could explain that as well.

Comment: It;s interesting that initialization order depends not on initialization list sequence but [on the declaration order in the class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1242835). [It is required because](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242830/constructor-initialization-list-evaluation-order#comment1069647_1242835) class can have multiple constructors, and the only destuctor should destroy fields in definite reverse order.