# c++ singleton with static variable allocated with new

Tags: c++, c++11, static, singleton

recently I saw a piece of code as follows :

```
namespace {
    mutex* get_server_factory_lock() {
        static mutex server_factory_lock;
        return &server_factory_lock;
    }

    typedef std::unordered_map<string, ServerFactory*> ServerFactories;
    ServerFactories* server_factories() {
        static ServerFactories* factories = new ServerFactories; 
        // is variable factories assigned every time this function called ? 
        return factories;
    }
}  // namespace

/* static */
void ServerFactory::Register(const string& server_type,
                         ServerFactory* factory) {
    mutex_lock l(*get_server_factory_lock());
    if (!server_factories()->insert({server_type, factory}).second) {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Two server factories are being registered under "
            << server_type;
    }
}
```

It seems that function `server_factories()` is similar to the singleton.
My question is : to the best of my knowledge, `factories` is a static variable, and every time function `server_factories()` called, this static variable will be assigned a new value. But the result is not, every time `server_factories()` is called, it returns the same pointer. Why?

PS : with c++11 enabled when compiling.

Duplicated with [What is the lifetime of a static variable in a C++ function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246564/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-static-variable-in-a-c-function)

Comment: In both functions, static variable is only initialized once.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ok, thanks. But I still wonder why `static ServerFactories* factories = new ServerFactories; ` is considered as initialization, not an assignment when `server_factories()` called in the second time.

Comment: Look at [whats-the-difference-between-assignment-operator-and-copy-constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706040/whats-the-difference-between-assignment-operator-and-copy-constructor)

Comment: @Jarod42  that link didn't help. I think it's an assignment operation, not copy operation. If so, the `factories` variable should be changed every time `server_factories()` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a static, so it only gets initialized once, when you first enter the function. Later calls to the same function use the previous variable. That said, I fail to see why it's a pointer and not a simple function static variable (with automatic storage duration) that we could take the address of...

Comment: "That said, I fail to see why it's a pointer and not a simple static that we could take the address of" << Because perhaps `ServerFactories()` uses other global variables. If it were also a global, initialization order across translation units would be undefined. By making it a function-local static, initialization order becomes well-defined. Whether this is needed in his case is unknown, but this is a frequent reason for this pattern.

Comment: @DarkFalcon thanks.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: in `get_server_factory_lock()`, there is no `new`, and you can still have well defined behavior. There is no points to do allocation.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: by simple static I mean static within the function, but not pointer (sorry if my wording was confusing), like this: ServerFactories* server_factories() {
        static ServerFactories factories; 
        return &factories;
    }

Editing the answer accordingly.

Comment: @lorro, fair enough. Might want to clarify that. The correct terminology is (I think) "function static variable with automatic storage duration"