# assigning class a value on declaration does not compile

Tags: c++, initialization, variable-assignment

I want to assign a class a value on declaration so I made this basic class:

```
class   A
{
public:
    A   &operator=(int)
    {
        return (*this);
    }
};
```

and compiled it with this main:

```
int main(void)
{
    A x = 1;
}
```

but the compiler complained with this error message:

```
no viable conversion from 'int' to 'A'

    A x = 1;
      ^   ~
```

but when I compile with this main:

```
int main(void)
{
    A x;

    x = 1;
}
```

everything compiles smoothly

---

why does my first main not compile and how can I change the class A so that it compiles?

Comment: Not exactly the case in your question, but will probably shed some light on it for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706040/whats-the-difference-between-assignment-operator-and-copy-constructor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`A x = 1;` is initialization, not assignment; they're different things. It doesn't invoke assignment operator but requires [converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor).

```
class   A
{
public:
    // converting constructor
    A (int) {} 

    A   &operator=(int)
    {
        return (*this);
    }
};
```

then

```
A x = 1; // initialize x via converting constructor
x = 2;   // assign x via assignment operator
```