# Why do I need a copy constructor for type T?

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor

I am a little uncertain when the copy constructor is needed. For example, given this function:

```
template<class T>
T max(const T* array, int size) {
    T result = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        if (result < array[i]) {
            result = array[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

What is the reason that I need a copy constructor for the type `T`? I think it must be because we return by value. Does this line `T result = array[0];` also need the copy constructor?

Comment: The return line will use move constructor.

Comment: While something like this is good as an exercise, once it's done and you learned something from it you should throw it away and use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) instead.

Comment: @songyuanyao Thank you about your answer, but it's not explain me why is needed..

Comment: Don't let presence of `=` confuse you. This line is actually a copy-initialization syntax for a  constructor call.

Comment: @VTT It's not `operator=` ?

Comment: Nope, it is not `operator =`. It is actually a good ideal to never use this syntax for initialization.

Comment: @VTT Why it is not `=` operator?

Comment: @VTT Ok, it's nice to know it. So how can I know when it's a copy constructor and when it's `operator=`?

Comment: The line `T result = array[0];` is copy-construction of `result` (it's equal to `T result(array[0]);`). The line `result = array[i];` is assignment to `result`.

Comment: @BonjeFir Because it is copy-initialization syntax. When `=` is used to assign a value during variable initialization it invokes copy constructor, not an assignment operator. Why is it like this? No idea. To my opinion copy initialization should've been deprecated long ago.

Comment: One reason for the syntax is that you write `int i = 1;`to initialize a variable in C. Bjarne wanted C++ to be able to do `T i = 1;` for any `T`, not just the primitive types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the reason that I need `copy constructor` for the type `T`?

```
T result = array[0];
```

This is known as a copy initialization and invokes the copy constructor for the type `T`. Type `T` will *require* a copy constructor for this line to succeed.

> I think that it's must be because that we return by a value, and so we need `copy constructor` for `T` type.

```
return result;
```

For the most part, your assumption is correct for the return value. However, it isn't necessary for a copy constructor to be defined in this case. To implement [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics), you can implement a move constructor which will remove the need for the copy constructor, since the local variable `result` will be "moved" instead of "copied" from. Move semantics remove the need for unnecessary copies of large objects when returning them from a function, since those large objects will not be accessible after the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

This was already answered here:

> [What's the difference between assignment operator and copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706040/whats-the-difference-between-assignment-operator-and-copy-constructor)

So the thing is:

A **copy constructor** is used to initialize a **previously uninitialized** object from some other object's data.

An **assignment operator** is used to replace the data of a **previously initialized** object with some other object's data.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class MyClass{
public:
  MyClass(){
    cout << "Default ctor\n";
  }

  MyClass(const MyClass& copyArg){
    cout << "Copy ctor\n";
  }

  MyClass(MyClass&& moveArg){
    cout << "Move ctor\n";
  }

  void operator=(const MyClass& assignArg){
    cout << "Assignment operator\n";
  }

  bool operator<(const MyClass& comparsionArg) const {
    return true;
  }
};

template<class T>
T max(const T* array, int size) {
    T result = array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (result < array[i]) {
            result = array[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}


int main(){

  MyClass arr[1];

  const MyClass& a = max(arr, 1);

  return 0;
}
```

To see what's exactly happening [we need to compile with `-fno-elide-constructors`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).

The output is:

```
Default ctor
Copy ctor
Assignment operator
Move ctor
```

So here, the **default constructor** is called at this line for one element of array:

```
MyClass arr[1];
```

Then we initialize a **previously uninitialized** object and **copy constructor** is called:

```
T result = array[0];
```

Then we make an assignment to **previously initialized** object and **assignment operator** called:

```
result = array[i];
```

After we need to create object outside of our function scope since we return by value and for that **move constructor** called:

```
return result;
```

Then bind object constructed with **move constructor** in `main` scope to const reference:

```
const MyClass& a = max(arr, 1);
```