# Difference between assignment of tags using " " and ' '

Tags: html, angular

So im learning angular and came to switch statements, however I have a confusion as to the assignment of the div tags for the switch statements regarding the **quotation makrs**. This is the html code:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="color">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="red">You picked red color</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="blue">You picked blue color</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="green">You picked green color</div>
</div>
```

and I have declared a variable `color` in my `.ts` file

```
export class StructuralDividesComponent implements OnInit {
public color="red"; 
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

Why does this code only work if the `color` value is in `"'red'"` and not in `"red"`.

Comment: check this plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706040/whats-the-difference-between-assignment-operator-and-copy-constructor

Comment: `"'red'"` will treat red as a string while `"red"` will treat red as a property in the component if you define `private red='red'` in your component it will work

Answer (score 3):

I think this is core javaScript concept. When you give *ngSwitchCase="red" it tries to find the red variable from its component and replaces the value. But If you want to match it with a string value then you must have to write *ngSwitchCase="'red'"

For more, you can see -> [When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you so much. The thing is im used to using single quotes rather than double because its much easier in typing hence the confusion

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, when you declare `*ngSwitchCase="'red'"` then the **red** is considered a string and angular doesn't search for it in the component's properties. If you declare `*ngSwitchCase="red"` then it considers it a variable (component's property) and tries to find it inside the component. In other words, the **angular expects a javascript inside all its native directives.**