# Can I move an object from the beginning of a vector? Why not?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

[This](https://rextester.com/UFJHZ48680) does not compile. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct test_s {
    int a;

    test_s& operator=(test_s &&ts) {
        a = ts.a;
        ts.a = 0;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main ()
{
  std::vector<test_s> v;

  test_s ss = std::move(v.front());

  return 0;
}
```

Error(s):

```
source_file.cpp:20:10: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'test_s'
  test_s ss = std::move(v.front());
         ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
source_file.cpp:9:13: note: copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'test_s' has a user-declared move assignment operator
    test_s& operator=(test_s &&ts) {
            ^
1 error generated
```

Is it possible to move an object from vector(without the call to copy assignment operator)?

Comment: You are invoking *move constructor*, not *move assignment operator*.

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve? Do you want to remove the first element from the vector?

Comment: btw your code has UB, because there is no `v.front()` that you could move, the vector has zero elements

Comment: You need to also provide a **move constructor** for the `test_s` type

Comment: Similar question for copy contructor and copy assignment operator: [What's the difference between assignment operator and copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706040/whats-the-difference-between-assignment-operator-and-copy-constructor)

Comment: lools like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Also note that usually moving is done to be more efficient than a copy, but in your example a simple copy would be cheaper

Comment: You basically cannot use a vector with a value type that has neither copy constructor nor move constructor. Which is your case.

Comment: OK. Thank you all. But looks like I oversimplefied my code example. Will try to investignate what is going on further...

Comment: Well... In my "real" code it was the opposite. I wrote move constructor but forgot about move assignment operator. That was the problem.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 it is very difficult to ask on SO. If OP puts a lot of code he will be asked to create minimal example. If OP provides minimal you complain there is no reason to move. OP does not have to create an example where move is necessary.

Comment: @AlexandrFadeev no you did not oversimplify, you just need to know that despite `=` you have object creation here, not assignment. It should compile if you do this `test_s ss; ss = std::move( v.front() );`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 _in your example a simple copy would be cheaper_ . Thanks, but it is not only about efficiency, I use move to transfer control of a "resource" so that it will be "released" properly.

Comment: @AlexandrFadeev strictly speaking also that isnt the case for your example. The control of the `int` member is not transfered to the moved-to object, you just pretend so by copying it and setting it to `0` and nothing has to be released here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This does not compile. Why?

Because your struct `test_s` needs a *move constructor* (or a *copy constructor*).

The statement:

```
test_s ss = std::move(v.front());
```

**constructs** the object `ss`. Although you see the `=` sign, this is not an *assignment*.

However, you have defined a *move assignment* in your struct.

In accordance with [this table](https://foonathan.net/images/special-member-functions.png), when the user defines the *move assignment*, the *move constructor* is not provided by the compiler. Moreover, the *move* operation should "fallback" on the copy but (as you see in the table), the *copy constructor* is implicitly deleted (as your compiler suggests as well).

> Is it possible to move an object from vector(without the call to copy assignment operator)?

Well, yes.

You should define your own *move constructor* for your class. 
Actually, you should follow the [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

**Note:**
Be also aware that your code has an *undefined behavior* as you are trying to access to a not existing element in the vector (as pointed out by some comments).