# copy constructor and assignment operator in C++

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, copy-constructor

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    MyClass(int x)
    {
        this->x = x;
    }
    MyClass(const MyClass& other)
    {
        this->x = other.x;
    }
};

int main()
{

    MyClass first(1);
    MyClass second = first;        //(1)
    first = second;               // (2)
    MyClass third = MyClass(2);  //  (3)     
}
```

Why the first line `MyClass second = first` calls the copy constructor and the second `first = second;`  calls the assignment operator, and why the third `MyClass third = MyClass(2);` did not act like line one by calling the copy constructor.
Finlly, what exactly line 3 do `MyClass third = MyClass(2);`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between assignment operator and copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706040/whats-the-difference-between-assignment-operator-and-copy-constructor)

Comment: When an object is already constructed, it cannot be constructed again. C++ does not work this way. Therefore its assignment operator must be called. As far as what line 3 does, it's called "copy elision". However, your question needs to be reframed, there's only one question per Stackoverflow question, please. Please [edit] your question to focus it only on the copy constructor vs assignment question, or on copy elision. And before posting your 1st question to Stackoverflow you should take the [tour], read the [help] and learn [ask] questions here.

Comment: There are distinct meanings of `=` in general: (1) is a declaration with initialization. Here, `=` is the "separator" between declaration and initializer. (2) is an expression. Here, `=` is the assignment operator. It might be confusing that the same symbol has different meanings depending in which context it appears. However, you already may have noticed that `=` is not the only such symbol. E.g. the `*` and `&` have very different meanings as well depending on where they occur...

Comment: This question is about a piece of code where similar things (assigning objects and launching constructors) are done one after the other, and the author seems not to understand the difference between both. This is a good, even a valuable question, and I disagree about this question being some "You are not paying attention" test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors, including copy constructors, are for initializing a class object. Assignment operators are for modifying an object which was already initialized.

Line (1) calls a copy constructor because it is initializing the object `second`. The assignment operator has nothing to do with the fact that the `=` symbol is also used in this syntax.  Line (2) assigns to `first` which already exists, so uses the assignment operator.

In C++14 and earlier for line (3), the compiler is allowed to create a temporary object for the `MyClass(2)` expression, then use the copy constructor to initialize `third`, then destroy the temporary. But the compiler is also allowed to "elide" (remove) the temporary object, the copy constructor, and the temporary destructor, just initializing `third` directly in the same way as the original temporary. This copy elision is the one case where C++ allows an optimization which can cause a difference in observable behavior, since the copy constructor and/or destructor might have side effects (like printing traces) which the optimization skips.

In C++17 and later for line (3), we say that the expression `MyClass(2)` has result object `third`. So the expression specifies that `third` is direct-initialized with argument `2`. No copy constructor or temporary object is involved. This feature of C++17 is often called "mandatory copy elision", since the behavior is the same as a C++14 program where the compiler was able to apply the copy elision optimization. But technically it's not a copy elision, since there is no copy involved to elide. There are still some other cases where copy elision is optional for the compiler.