# What's behind the curtain of std::vector range initialization?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector, allocation

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include "iostream"

class Person {
public:
    std::string name{"no-name"};

    Person() {
        std::cout << std::string("Person()") << std::endl;
    }

    explicit Person(std::string name) : name(std::move(name)) {
        std::cout << std::string("Person(") + this->name + ")" << std::endl;
    }

    // operator =
    Person &operator=(const Person &other) {
        std::cout << std::string("operator= ") + other.name + "->" + this->name + "" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    Person(const Person &other) noexcept {
        std::cout << std::string("copy ") + other.name + "->" + this->name + "" << std::endl;
        this->name = other.name;
    }

    // move
    Person(Person &&other) noexcept {
        std::cout << std::string("move ") + other.name + "->" + this->name + "" << std::endl;
        this->name = std::move(other.name);
    }

    ~Person() {
        std::cout << std::string("~Person(") + name + ")" << std::endl;
    }

};

int main() {

    std::cout << "construct person_list" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Person> person_list (4);

    std::cout << "construct person_list_copy" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Person> person_list_copy (person_list.begin(), person_list.end());
}
```

output:

```
construct person_list
Person()
Person()
Person()
Person()
construct person_list_copy
copy no-name->no-name
copy no-name->no-name
copy no-name->no-name
copy no-name->no-name
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
```

Where does the enough space of vector "person_list_copy" come from before the copy operation took place?

I think the vector is much like a C-style fixed-size array, we firstly need to have enough space where I think the default constructor should be called, and then we assign some objects into those pre-constructed "cells", at which I think copy constructor should be called.

The code above directly creates object with copy constructor, but how is that possible to put an object into an array before the space of the array is constructed?

I never saw something like this before in terms of C programming. And I can't figure out an available way to achieve something like what std::vector does with all terminologies I've got so far, like 'new', uint8_t fixed_array[LEN], malloc.

I'm a C++ beginner, and there must be some misunderstanding of vector range initialization in my head, or may be there are some magics I don't know yet about C++ and STL.

**Expected output**

```
construct person_list
Person()
Person()
Person()
Person()
construct person_list_copy
Person()
Person()
Person()
Person()
copy no-name->no-name
copy no-name->no-name
copy no-name->no-name
copy no-name->no-name
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
~Person(no-name)
```

Comment: The vector allocates enough memory to store all elements of the vector, but doesn't construct the elements. Then it copy-constructs the elements in-place (basically it does placement new).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude And that is actually quite important because this works with a class that doesn't have a default constructor! Types in ordinary arrays need one, which is terrible if the proper constructors initialize the object properly, creating an invariant. So being able to copy properly initialized objects around is essential.

Comment: I think your expected output is missing assignments. Either you default-construct the internal array elements; then you must copy-construct *an extra temp;* which is then assigned to the array element. Or you copy-construct in place, which is what happens. When you compare the two options it's clear why the copy-construct-in-place was chosen. ;-)

Comment: Please see [ask], in particular the part about asking your question **before** your code. Not only would it make your post easier to read, but also it is likely to trick you into formulating your question better (since you can't assume the code has been read and 100% understood).

Comment: *"then we assign some objects into it, at which copy constructor should be called"* -- Assignment is not construction. Your copy assignment does not construct anything, so no constructors are called during assignment. See [What's the difference between assignment operator and copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11706040)

Comment: @OP Read about `new` and `placement new` and allocators etc.

Comment: @Peter - Reinstate Monica Yes you mentioned a great point, I missed the assignment operation in my expected result, thank you for point that out. What I need to do is to know more about what you called "copy-construct-in-place".

Comment: @JaMiT Thank you for point that out. I'll try to put my question before code in my later question. And yes, that's a mistake that I've wrongly called the assignment operator "copy constructor", I do know the distinction about assignment operator and copy constructor, the "copy constructor should be called" is a mistake.

Comment: @strideraron You should also be outputting the value of `this` in your constructors, destructor, and assignment operator so that you know what objects are being created,  destroyed, and assigned to.  You really can't learn easily with just a wall of text that has no context to it.  Outputting `this` puts context into those output statements.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Actually I already have done what you described, I originally wanted to mark the context information with the field "name: std::string", but in consideration of to make the main as simple as possible, I delete those irrelevant construction like: Person("marry"). In my local workshop I do have pay attention to the context information.

Comment: @OP yes that's exactly what I need to know all about the question.

Answer (score 1):

How `std::vector` constructs the new elements depend on the template parameter `Allocator`. `std::vector<T, Allocator>` calls `Allocator::allocate` to reserve the memory and `Allocator::construct`(Before C++11) or `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct`(Since C++11) to actually construct the elements. These functions take an address to construct the object along with the parameters to be forwarded to the actual constructor, and should construct the element in place.

The memory allocation and the element construction are two separate steps and there is no need to default-construct the elements first. If the elements have to be default constructed first, it would not be possible to use `std::vector` for non-default-constructible types, but it is perfectly valid to have `std::vector<S>` where `S` is not a default-constructible type. In fact, the requirement for the `element_type` used for `std::vector` depends on the actual functions to be called, but the bare minimum is that the element is [Erasable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Erasable). Default constructible is a much more strict condition than erasable and is not required.

The default parameter for `Allocator` is `std::allocator`. For `std::allocator`, both `Allocator::construct` (before C++11) and `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct` (after C++11, and via the call to `std::construct_at` after C++20) both ultimately calls [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) to construct the objects in already allocated memory. If you use a custom `Allocator` template parameter, it is possible that default construction is performed before construction of actual element, but it is unusual to do so and not efficient anyway.

Specifically addressing your misunderstandings:

> Where does the enough space of vector "person_list_copy" come from before the copy operation took place ?

It's from `Allocator::allocate()` (before C++11) or `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate()` (after C++11). For `std::allocator`, this is equivalent to calling `operator new()`. I think you may be confused about the `new` keyword and the global allocation function `operator new()`. The latter only allocates uninitialized memory and is quite similar to `std::malloc`, except that it has to be paired with `operator delete` instead of `std::free`.

There are already many duplicates addressing the difference between `new` keyword and `operator new`, but to briefly recap, when you do `p=new Person;`, first `operator new()` is called to allocate the memory, then the default constructor is called. However, it is perfectly valid to just call `operator new()` to allocate the memory without invoking any constructor, and that is exactly what is happening for `std::vector` allocation with `std::allocator`.

> I can't figure out an available way to achieve something like what std::vector does with all terminologies I've got so far, like 'new', uint8_t fixed_array[LEN], malloc.

I guess the missing piece is `operator new()` and how it is different from a `new` expression.

Comment: Should not it be "`Allocator::construct` (before C++11)"?

Comment: @LoS Thank you for pointing out my misunderstanding. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's what C++ can do and does if possible. Allocates empty memory first, calls constructors later. *std* classes are intentionally written to do this to save CPU time.

In C++ you have full control over the raw memory and you can choose to do with it as you please. Including stuff like leaving it uninitialized or forcibly calling initialization on an arbitrary chunk of memory.

See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/placement-new-operator-cpp/ for example of how it can be done under the hood.

Comment: [geeksforgeeks.org](https://geeksforgeeks.org) is definitely not somewhere you should recommend for expert advice.

Comment: Well, but this was a beginner question apparently asked by someone who switches to C++ from a language where you don't have this type of control over objects and memory. So I think it's appropriate.

Comment: @MBobrik This is even more dangerous because we should not suggest bad sites like geeksforgeeks to beginners. They are beginners and don't know if a site is a good source or not.

Comment: Didn't know the site has a bad rep this big. Good to know. But anyway, the question already got preexisting answers so its not rly that relevant.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Well I agree with you that geeksforgeeks.org is not that "formal", and I quite know this truth. And with all c, java, python programming  experiences I've got, I know the importance to consult to official site(for cpp, it would be cppreference.com). But on the other side, what MBobrik has done is providing a way to get quick through the new terminologies that I don't know, so I think it's ok to have a glance at the site. By the way thank you guys for trying to get me correct at the path of  learning tech.

Comment: *”…official site(for cpp, it would be cppreference.com)”* consult the ISO C++ Standard. But to concede, I’ve got to say [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com) is good (98% accurate -no statistical data to back this up, just my opinion) but for a beginner, I would recommend [learncpp.com](https://learncpp.com)