# C++ operator = problems

Tags: c++, operators

I have a MyPoly class where I implemented my own equal operator ( = ).
When I try this code everything works fine and my implemented = is being called.

```
MyPoly mp = MyPoly(arr , 4); 

MyPoly copy;
copy = mp;
```

But when I write this:

```
MyPoly mp = MyPoly(arr , 4); 

MyPoly copy = mp;
```

It doesn't use my implemented = , and then when the destructor is called I get a run time error.

Can someone explain why these codes are different?

Comment: I think in the second case, the copy constructor is used instead of the assignment operator.

Comment: I'm leaving, so I don't have time for a full answer, but this is due to the unfortunate fact that C++ uses the symbol `=` for both *assignment* (first case) and *initialization* (second case).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line

```
MyPoly copy = mp;
```

is a **copy initialization**, so it does not call the assignment operator (what you refer to as "equal operator"), but rather the copy constructor, which has signature

```
MyPoly(const MyPoly&);
```

and is generated by the compiler unless you provide your own. As to the runtime error, you need to provide more code. But I could speculate that, since you have written your own assignment operator, you may be dealing with some dynamically allocated resources, in which case you should follow the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) and implement your own copy constructor and destructor. And if you have C++11 support, you should extend that into the [rule of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) and provide your own move copy constructor and move assignment operator.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
MyPoly copy = mp;
```

is not assignment, but **copy initialization**. It uses the copy constructor, not the assignment operator.

```
MyPoly copy(mp);
```

is **direct initialization**.

```
MyPoly copy;
copy = mp;
```

is **assignment**.

Answer (score 3):

```
MyPoly mp = MyPoly(arr , 4); 

MyPoly copy = mp;
```

Calls `copy c-tor`, not `operator =`. It's `copy initialization` in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

```
MyPoly copy = mp;
```

Is the same as:

```
MPoly copy(mp);
```

As in, it invokes the copy constructor instead of the assignment operator. Creating a copy constructor alongside an assignment operator is always a good idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222076/why-is-copy-constructor-called-instead-of-conversion-constructor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati

Comment: It's the same *in that* they both invoke the copy ctor. They differ in other respects. Folks from NOLA talk different anyways ;-)

Comment: I meant "equal on the terms that they both invoke the copy constructor", not absolutely equal. Inadequate and wrong wording of my thoughts :-(.