# int a = 0 and int a(0) differences

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati)

I just started to learn C++.

To initialize a variable with a value, I came across

```
int a = 0;
```

and

```
int a(0);
```

This confuses me a lot. May I know which is the best way?

Comment: For an built in data type like `int` both are same. For an custom class they might mean different.

Comment: I won't mention "int a {0}" then to avoid adding to the confusion :)

Comment: @J99 So is `int a{0}` similar to defining an integer object array of size 1 and assigning it a value of 0?

Comment: No, it's the new c++11 way to initialize anything. It's just the same as "int a(0)" in this case.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`int a = 0;` and `int a(0);` make no difference in the machine generated code. They are the same.

Following is the assembly code generated in Visual Studio

```
int a = 10;   // mov dword ptr [a],0Ah  
int b(10);    // mov dword ptr [b],0Ah
```

Comment: I love the example shown in assembly code.

Comment: However, just because the generated code is the same, it does not mean  that the language features are the same. Trying to learn the language by Black Box methods, as in "running the programs" and/or "inspecting the assembly" usually leads to massive misconceptions.

Comment: @SeeJay what machine code does `char c = 10;` generate? I'm curious whether `char` and `int` are the same...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I've just tested it's `move byte ptr [c], 0Ah` In case of `8 bits it's byte`, `16 bit => word`, `32 bit => dword`, `64 bit => qword`.

Comment: What about an `unsigned int`? (maybe I gave the wrong example initially, the point is the machine code proves **nothing**)

Comment: @AndreyT yes you are right, in high level the concept can mean different thing. I'm aware that in Class Type and Primitive type, they are different. Sometimes I prefer to understand it in low level way, such by using assembly code or intermediate code.

Comment: For a more in detail explanation see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati

Answer (score 23):

They're both the same, so there really is no one *"best way"*.

I personally use

```
int a = 0;
```

because I find it more clear and it's more widely used in practice.

*This applies to your code, where the type is `int`. For class-types, the first is copy-initialization, whereas the other is direct-initialization, so in that case it would make a difference*.

Comment: For class types B b(a); and B b = a; actually are same and both use copy constructor to initialize. So there's no different. B b; b=a; use assign operator and then you have completely other case.

Comment: @Dainius nope, they are not.

Comment: @Dainius see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222076/why-is-copy-constructor-called-instead-of-conversion-constructor

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: You are beast in `C++`. You answers are `very clear` and `to the point`. Thanks for all the good work you are doing.

Comment: #include <iostream>

class A { public: A() {}; };
class B 
{
public:
   B() { std::cout << "B ctr\n"; }
   B(const A&) { std::cout << "B ctr with a\n"; }
   B& operator = (const A&) { std::cout << "B operator = with A\n"; return *this; }
};

int main(void)
{
   A a;
   B b1(a);
   B b2 = a;
   return 0;
} // output is B ctr with a for both calls, how it's not same?

Comment: from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor "X b = a;       // valid if any of the copy constructors are defined"

Comment: looks like it depends on compilator, so probably it's possible that some still creates temporary objects and not direct call for copy constructor.

Comment: @Dainius: Where is the copy constructor you promised? Firstly, `B(const A&)` is *not* a copy constructor. Yet you said initially that "both use copy constructor". Your example contradicts your own statements. Secondly, the difference between `A a; B b(a);` and `A a; B b = a` is that the later actually does use `B`'s copy constructor (unless it gets optimized away), while the former doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

There's no "best" way. For scalar types (like `int` in your example) both forms have exactly the same effect.

The `int a(0)` syntax for non-class types was introduced to support uniform direct-initialization syntax for class and non-class types, which is very useful in type-independent (template) code.

In non-template code the `int a(0)` is not needed. It is completely up to you whether you want to use the `int a(0)` syntax, or prefer to stick to more traditional `int a = 0` syntax. Both do the same thing. The latter is more readable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

From a practical point of view: I would **only** use `int a = 0;`.

The `int a(0)` may be allowed but never used in practice in itself.

---

I think it should not bother you on your level, but let us go further.

Let's say that `a` is a class, not an int.

```
class Demo{
public:
  Demo(){}; 
  Demo(int){};
};
Demo a;
Demo b(a);   
Demo c = a;  // clearly expressing copy-init
```

In this example both `b(a)` and `c=a` do the same, and I would discourage you using the fist solution. My reason is, that is looks similar to `c(2)` which is a construction from arguments.

There are only two **valid uses** of this bracket-style initialization:

- initialization lists (`Demo(int i):data(i){}` if Demo has an int data member `data`),
- new's: `Demo *p=new Demo(a); // copy constructing a pointer`

Comment: a thrid use case would be creating a template object, where the = may or may not be overloaded

Answer (score 2):

It’s that simple. (Well, almost — there are a few things you can’t name your variables, which we’ll talk about in the next section)

You can also assign values to your variables upon declaration. When we assign values to a variable using the assignment operator (equals sign), it’s called an explicit assignment:

```
int a= 5; // explicit assignment
```

You can also assign values to variables using an implicit assignment:

```
int a(5); // implicit assignment
```

Even though implicit assignments look a lot like function calls, the compiler keeps track of which names are variables and which are functions so that they can be resolved properly.

Comment: It is *not* called assignment. *Assignment* is a reserved term in C++ terminology with a strictly defined and very specific meaning. Referring to *initialization* as "assignment" will only create unnecessary confusion. The proper terms for this two forms of initialization syntax are *direct-initialization* and *copy-initialization*.

Comment: class A { public: A(int) {} }; class B { public: B(const A&) {}}; B b1(10); B b2 = 20; // compiles and run.  If need explicit then it should be said in declaration like explicit A(int) {}

Answer (score 0):

In textbooks and literature, one is direct initialization and the other is copy initialization. But, in terms of machine code, there is no difference.

Comment: Yup; the difference gets significant when constructors are involved

Answer (score -2):

The difference is that `()` initialization is when you explicitly want it to take one parameter only, e.g:

You can:
`int a = 44 + 2;`
but you can't:
`int a(44) + 2;`

Comment: but you can do:
         int a(44+2);       
So that's not a significant difference.