# How to find the highest number of passenger of all round?

Tags: c++

im a new problem solver. recently i came across this [problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/116/A) on codeforces website. i managed to get the two values required for each turn depending on the number of turn given by the user, but i cant find the highest number of passenger at stop out of all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int turn,get_off,get_on,total_passenger,highest_total;
    cin>>turn;
    int* stops=new int(turn);
    for(int i=0;i<turn;i++){
        cin>>get_off>>get_on;
        total_passenger=get_on-get_off;
        stops[i]=total_passenger;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<turn;i++){
        if(stops[i]>stops[i+1]){
            highest_total=stops[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<highest_total<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int* stops=new int(turn);` Allocates a single `int`. Did you mean `int* stops=new int[turn];`?

Comment: stackoverflow.com is not a web site for "problem solvers" but for ***specific*** questions on programming topics. All questions here must have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. This question must be [edit]ed, and all links removed and replaced with all relevant information, as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text. There's no reason why this one can't, either.

Comment: why are you doing stops[i] with an Int pointer?

Comment: yess, but after i corrected it, the answer is still wrong. i think my logic is wrong here and i cant find out what it is

Comment: [Why using namespace std; is considered bad practise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initiate stops as an array I guess(`int stops[turn]`) as C++ now offers to allocate memory this way even inside any function. That may solve your problem.

Alongside you will have to check corner cases as your **highest_total** variable may provide garbage value. So while declaring the variable assign a value to it. I prefer initializing **int highest_total=-1** here.

Actually you dont need an array or pointer here. This can be solved this way-

```
#include<cstring>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int turn,get_off,get_on,total_passenger=0;
    cin>>turn;
    int highest_total=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<turn;i++){
        cin>>get_off>>get_on;
        total_passenger=total_passenger+get_on-get_off;
        if(total_passenger>highest_total)
             highest_total=total_passenger;
    }
    cout<<highest_total<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried it exactly like this i remember, but it gives wrong answer. in this code, we only get the difference of each turn, but we should be also adding the previous value to new turn, this makes me so cinfused

Comment: this is why i used pointer array to store them and then compare, otherwise id have to declare 4 variable for them

Comment: I have edited my code and hope now you get accepted. Basically just initialized total_passenger variable to '0' and each time inside for loop added the value with the previous **total_passenger** value.

Comment: Ahh. Feels good to help. Actually it can also be done with the pointers and arrays. But some of my teachers advised me not to use pointers where it is not actually necessary as it creates problem with your programs efficiency.

Comment: @Maisha as Raju says this can be done with pointers aswell, although I would not claim this reduces the efficiency but instead you might have to deal with memory allocation. I provided some links in my answer who might help you get started.

Comment: @RajuAhmed im so inclined to that idea because it came to my mind first when thinking of how to solve this problem. if im not being overly annoying and of course if you arent busy and dont mind to help, can you give me some ideas why my code is failing? i still wanna fix my original code since there is no reason why it shouldnt work

Comment: @darclander yes, i will look into it now, thank you :)

Comment: @Maisha if any of these answers helped you / made you resolve your issues you could upvote them and mark one answer who answered your question to help people who might get the same problem in the future!

Answer (score 1):

you can try using https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element
also you set the total passengers number to the difference between get off and get on and I think you should just add that difference, and to allocate memory for int* you use [] instead of ()

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int turn,get_off,get_on,total_passenger,highest_total;
    cin>>turn;
    int* stops=new int[turn];
    for(int i=0;i<turn;i++){
        cin>>get_off>>get_on;
        total_passenger+=get_on-get_off;
        stops[i]=total_passenger;
    }
    cout<<std::max_element(stops, stops + turn)<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with `int *stops = new int(turn)`. It will allocate memory for `1` integer. 
Use `int stops[turn]` and your algorithm need to be modified.
`stop[i] += total_passenger` need to be used with some `if-else`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: `int* stops=new int(turn);` initializes a pointer to a new int with the value `turn`. See [int a = 0 and int a(0) differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738996/int-a-0-and-int-a0-differences)

Instead you should either use `int* stops=new int[turn];`, read about when you should use new here: [When should I use the new keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655065/when-should-i-use-the-new-keyword-in-c). An important note is that you have to delete the variable in order to avoid a [Memory leak](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-leak-in-c-and-how-to-avoid-it/).

Or (which I would say is the case you should use in this scenario), `int stops[turn];`. 
Besides that I can not argue with your logic since I believe this is not a forum to help you solve code, although the syntax seems correct.

I would recommend reading [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) if you are interested in learning C++ though.