# Types in copy constructor

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati)

```
Class A
{
public:
   //some member function call
private:
   int x;
   char a;
};
int main()
{
   A a;
   A b;
}
```

Hi can You tell me the Difference's in Between these when I call or initialize the objects of above class as

```
A a(b);
A a=b;
a=b;
```

Answer (score 3):

The first 2 lines calls the copy constructor because the objects are being constructed.
The last line will call the equals operator to perform the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

```
A a(b);
A a = b;
```

These use the implicitly generated [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor).

```
a = b;
```

This one uses the [assignment operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C%2B%2B%29), and it is **not an initialization**, since it does not create an `A` object: it just gives a new value to an existing one.

The copy constructor would have a signature such as

```
A(const A&);
```

and the assignment operator

```
A& operator=(const A&);
```

Since your class doesn't provide these, the compiler synthesizes them and just copies the data members.

Answer (score 1):

Since your class doesnt have any explicit copy constructor all of the above statements results in shallow copy.

If you have declared a copy constructor and overloaded the = operator then

A a(b) and A a= b will result in calling the copy constructor and

a= b will result in calling the = overloaded operator

Read [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/) for more understanding