# Shortcut for constructor

Tags: c++

Actually I don't know how to define this idioms.

In some code i have red something like:

```
ClassWithAMessage c = "This is the message";
```

where i expected to read:

```
ClassWithAMessage c("This is the message");
```

I don't know how to reproduce this behavior, can someone provide some information or a toy example?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClassWithAMessage c = "This is the message";
```

is **copy initialization**. A copy constructor must be available for this to work. First, a temporary `ClassWithAMessage` is constructed using the conversion constructor from `"This is the message"`. The temporary is then used with the copy constructor to construct `c`. This is subject to copy elision (the temp might not be there).

```
ClassWithAMessage c("This is the message");
```

is **direct initialization**. The conversion constructor is used directly.

Not really idioms, just different ways to construct an object.

Comment: In C++11 if a move constructor is available it will be used instead of the copy constructor for the first statement.