# Are these assignments on same pattern?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, default-constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortcut for constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463023/shortcut-for-constructor)

Are the following pieces of code the same in C++:

Piece1:

```
MyFunnyClass o = MyFunnyClass();
```

Piece2:

```
MyFunnyClass o;
```

I am aware that the following is not equivalent, but I am not sure about the two on the top:

```
MyFunnyClass o = MyFunnyClass () ;

MyFunnyClass o;
o = MyFunnyClass();
```

Comment: Wish I understood what exactly are you comparing to what ;-)

Comment: The first pair isn't equivalent, the second is.

Comment: This is not *really* a duplicate of that question, although it is related. The question marked as duplicate deals with *copy-initialization* vs. *direct-initialization*, while in this case it is *default-initialization* vs. *copy-initialization*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyFunnyClass o () ;
```

This does not define an object in any way at all. This is the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). `o` is a function which takes nothing and returns a `MyFunnyClass`, which you have declared.

The real syntax would be

```
MyFunnyClass o;
```

This would default-construct an object.

```
MyFunnyClass o = MyFunnyClass();
```

Value-constructs an object and then copies or moves it into `o`. Expect ellision here.

Comment: This is missing the most important bit of information: *default* vs. *value* initialization. The last case is *value* initialization, not *default* initialization

Comment: Good shout David, I'd forgotten about that.