# what is the different of initializing using () and =

Tags: c++, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati)

```
class Animal{};

int main(){    
  Animal white_cat;
  Animal black_cat(white_cat);
  Animal brown_cat = white_cat;    
}
```

I know here both initialization done by copy constructor. But performance or memory wise are there  any different among these two initializing?  `Animal black_cat(white_cat); Animal brown_cat = white_cat;` If not why are there two way to do the same thing?

Comment: `Animal black_cat(white_cat);` is **Direct Initialization**. While, `Animal brown_cat = white_cat;` is **Copy Initialization**.

Comment: @LucianGrigore: The are defined to have the same effect because `white_cat` has type `Animal`.