# Sane design for a class holding a shared resource

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Consider the following simplified example of a class holding a shared resource:

```
class array
{
    typedef std::array<float, 1000> resource;

public:
    // default constructor, creates resource
    array() : p_(std::make_shared<resource>()), a_(0), b_(1000) {}

    // create view
    array operator()(int a, int b) { return array(p_, a_+a, a_+b); }

    // get element
    float& operator[](int i) { return (*p_)[a_+i]; }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<resource> p_;
    int a_, b_;

    // constructor for views
    array(std::shared_ptr<resource> p, int a, int b) : p_(p), a_(a), b_(b) {}
};
```

Now I'm wondering how to define a semantics for this class that doesn't confuse its users. For example, I'd like to allow `operator=()` to copy elements:

```
array x, y;
x = y;                 // copies all elements from y's storage to x's
x(30,40) = y(50,60);   // copies 10 elements
```

But then, to be consistent, shouldn't the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator always copy? What about:

```
array z = x(80,90);    // will create an array referencing x's storage
```

In this case, the copy will be elided by the compiler, so no matter what my copy assignment operator does, `z` will hold a reference to `x`'s storage. There's no way around this.

So does it make more sense for assignment to always create a reference, and copying to be declared explicitly? For example, I could define a wrapper class `copy_wrapper`, assignment of which forces copying of elements:

```
class copy_wrapper
{
    array& a_;
public:
    explicit copy_wrapper(array& a) : a_(a) {}
    array& get() { return a_; }
};

class array
{
    // ...
    array& operator=(const array& a);    // references
    array& operator=(copy_wrapper c);    // copies
    copy_wrapper copy() { return copy_wrapper(*this); }
};
```

This would force users to write:

```
array x, y;
x(30,40) = y(50,60).copy();  // ok, copies
x(30,40) = y(50,60);         // should this throw a runtime error?
x = y;                       // surprise! x's resource is destructed.
```

A bit cumbersome, and worse than that: not what you expect.

How should I deal with this ambiguity?

Comment: In `array z = x`, it's actually the copy constructor which gets called, not the assignment operator. The copy constructor is what you should implement.

Comment: Also, you could use Python list semantics: `z=x` copies a reference, `z(1,10)=x(1,10)` copies a range, `z() = x()` copies everything.

Comment: Right, bad example. The assignment `array z = x;` is not eligible for copy elision, since `z` is not a temporary. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: again, the copy constructor will be called in `array z = x(80,90)`.

Comment: Generally, yes. But it depends. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1051468/728847). In any case, I'd like to implement the copy constructor and copy assignment operator in a way that they behave consistently, according the principle of least surprise.

Comment: @avakar No, it can be elided.

Comment: I'd suggest introducing the notion of `sub_array`, or `array_ref` or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. But I'd like the `subarray` to live on when the original `array` goes out of scope. So the whole discussion applies to `subarray`s then, just replace all occurrences of `array` above with `subarray`. Or am I overseeing something?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I get it now, I support @R.MartinhoFernandes on this, a separate type should be used to refer to array slices (which refer to an array) and arrays themselves (which own the data).

Comment: @marton78 if it keeps a `shared_ptr`, a subarray can live on after the original array leaves (basically, once you're dealing with shared_ptrs, there no such thing as "original" anymore).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Sure. That's why I wrote that in this case, the whole discussion applies to subarrays: `y(10,20) = x(10,20);` copies, `subarray y = x(10,20);` creates a new reference. Still inconsistent.

Comment: You should make subarrays have reference semantics (i.e. defaulted copy constructor and assignment) and arrays have value semantics (i.e. write copy constructor and assignment by hand that make copies)

Comment: But what should `subarray c = x(10,20); c = y(30,40);` do? 1) Re-reference to `y` or 2) overwrite a part of `x`? When 1), you have to keep in mind if `c` is an array or a subarray. When 2), copy-initialization and copy-assignment behave differently. That's the inconsistency that I mean.

Comment: May be not relevant but have you checked std::valarray class or std::slice function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Does it make more sense for assignment to always create a reference, and copying to be declared explicitly?*

In practice, **no**.  Expecting developers to remember that `a = b` will not copy is what got `std::auto_ptr` into hot water.  The C++11 standards committee also decided on `std::move` and `std::forward` to allow developers to *explicitly* say "I'm **not** making copies."

*What about: `array z = x(80,90);` In this case, the copy will be elided by the compiler, so no matter what my copy assignment operator does, z will hold a reference to x's storage. There's no way around this.*

This was your giveaway.  You want "array" and "view to an array" to act differently, but you're representing them both with class `array`.

Implement a new class `arrayview` with a similar public interface and move the ranges `a_` and `b_` to `arrayview`.

```
array x, y;
x = y;                  // "array = array" copies all elements
x(30,40) = y(50,60);    // "arrayview = arrayview" copies element range
arrayview v = x(80,90); // "arrayview(const arrayview&) shallow copies
x(30,40) = y;           // NOT DEFINED, since this has no clear meaning
array z = x(80,90);     // NOT DEFINED, since this has no clear meaning
```

Note that in your `arrayview` assignment operator, it should be valid to copy from an `arrayview` with the same resource, but in that specific case you should check whether `std::copy_backward` is needed instead of `std::copy`.

Comment: You're right. Arrays and views need different semantics and thus different class names. Thanks.