# Error: Conversion to non-scalar type

Tags: c++, cstring

I am making a set of derived classes for an assignment. I am instructed to use char arrays (c-strings). When I compile I keep getting the error:

```
Homework11.cpp: In function âint main()â:
Homework11.cpp:72: error: conversion from âchar [10]â to non-scalar type âBusinessâ requested
Homework11.cpp:73: error: conversion from âchar [10]â to non-scalar type âBusinessâ requested
Homework11.cpp:74: error: conversion from âchar [10]â to non-scalar type âAccountâ requested
Homework11.cpp:75: error: conversion from âchar [10]â to non-scalar type âAccountâ requested
```

I am fairly certain that my problem is originating up where I try to set the instance variable Name to the argument sent in. Here is my code with comments in where I believe the problems may be.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Person{
public:
        Person() {}
        Person(char theName[]) {strcpy(name,theName);}
        void getName(char theName[]) // I think the problem may be here or in the line above
                { theName = name;}
private:
        char name[80];
 };

class Account : public Person{
public:
        Account() :accountNum(0),balance(0) {}
        Account(int actNo, char theName[])
                :Person(theName),accountNum(actNo),balance(0) {}
        void setBal(float theBalance)
                {balance = theBalance;}
        void deposit(float numDeposited)
                { balance = balance + numDeposited;}
        float withdraw(float numWithdrawn)
                { balance = balance -numWithdrawn;
                  return numWithdrawn;}
        float getBal() {return balance;}
        void printBal();
private:
        int accountNum;
        float balance;
};

 class Business : public Account{
 public:
        Business() : checkFee(0.0) {}
        Business(int actNo, char theName[])
                : Account(actNo, theName),checkFee(0.0) {}
        float withdraw(float numWithdrawn)
                {float newBalance = getBal()-numWithdrawn-checkFee;
                 setBal(newBalance);
                  return numWithdrawn;}
        void setFee(float fee) {checkFee = fee;}
 private:
        float checkFee;
};

void Account::printBal()
{
        char name[80];
        getName(name);
        cout<<setw(10)<<"Account # "<<accountNum<<setw(10)<<
              name<<setw(10)<<balance<<endl;
}


int main()
{
        char businessName1[10]="Business1";
        char businessName2[10] ="Business2";
        char regularName1[10] = "Regular1";
        char regularName2[10] = "Regular2";

       //The following 4 lines are the ones I am getting the error for
        Business bs1 = (1,businessName1);
        Business bs2 = (2,businessName2);
        Account rg1 = (1, regularName1);
        Account rg2 = (2, regularName2);

        cout<<"Intially: "<<endl;
        rg1.printBal();
        rg2.printBal();
        bs1.printBal();
        bs2.printBal();

        bs1.deposit(1000.00);
        bs2.deposit(1000.00);
        rg1.deposit(1000.00);
        rg2.deposit(1000.00);

        cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<endl;
       cout<<"After adding 1000.00 to all accounts:"<<endl;
        rg1.printBal();
        rg2.printBal();
         bs1.printBal();
        bs2.printBal();

        bs1.setFee(1.00);
        bs1.withdraw(500);
        bs2.withdraw(500);
        bs1.deposit(250);
        bs2.deposit(250);
        rg1.withdraw(500);
        rg2.deposit(500);

        cout<<"---------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Finially:"<<endl;
        rg1.printBal();
        rg2.printBal();
        bs1.printBal();
        bs2.printBal();

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proper syntax would be `Business bs1(1,businessName1);`. If you want to use `=`, you can also use copy intialization `Business bs2 = Business(2,businessName2);`.

The former is known as direct initialization. They aren't exactly the same thing though, see [Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati) for in-depth information.

In `Business bs1 = (1,businessName1);` the `1` and array `businessName1` are separated by the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). The comma operator evaluates the first operand, i.e. `1` and throws away the results and returns the value of the second operand, which is an array in your case. In other words, your code is the equivalent of `Business bs1 = businessName1;`. This is why the error message says it cannot convert a `char[10]` to a `Business` object.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first line that produces an error to `Business bs1(1,businessName1);` and the rest similarly.  That's the C++ idiom for initialization of a class instance on the stack.

`Business bs2 = Business(2,businessName2);` as suggested by Jesse Good is, I'd argue, a Java idiom that is poor practice in C++.  It's slower because there are two implicit constructor calls and one copy constructor call, as opposed to the single constructor call in `Business bs1(1,businessName1);`.  In this case there is another trap: you have not defined a copy constructor for the `Business` type, which means that the compiler will create one for you that does a shallow copy.  `bs2.name` will end up a pointer to memory that isn't necessarily correctly freed when `bs2` goes out of scope--a classic memory leak.

The corresponding C++ idiom is instead to construct a new object on the heap, then assign its address to a pointer: `Business *bs2 = new Business(2,businessName2);`.

There's another problem with your code.  Generally, it's also bad style to assign arrays by name in C or C++ (and remember, statically allocated strings like `char theName[]` are just a special kind of array).  Look at the definition of `getName()` in `Person`:

```
void getName(char theName[])
    { theName = name; }
```

This is assigning the array names (which are not exactly pointers, but close cousins), not copying the contents of one string to another.  In `printBal()` you then write

```
char name[80];
getName(name);
```

When `getName()` executes it binds `printBal()`'s local variable `name` to the parameter `theName`.  So far, so good, although the variable names you choose could be a little less confusing. :)  But then the body of `getName()` executes and assigns the address of the private instance variable `name` to `theName` (which is the name of an array--again, a special kind of pointer).  When `getName()` returns, there's no permanent change to the local variable `name` in `printBal()`.  The correct way to write `Person::getName()` would be with `strcpy()`, the way you wrote the second `Person` constructor:

```
void getName(char theName[])
    { strcpy(theName,name); }
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. 1) Most likely the code will be optimized so that both forms are equivalent. 2) `name` is an **array**, not a pointer. The default copy constructor will be fine.

Comment: 1. I don't think you can make such a sweeping statement. As the discussion at the link you gave above (_Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?_) shows, there are a lot of complicated edge cases and compilers can't reliably optimize out those copy constructor calls.  I maintain that it's poor style.  C++ isn't Java.   2. You're right, but I think relying on the default copy constructor is also poor C++ style; also see my edited answer for another related problem with the original code.

Comment: If you don't believe me, how about a [quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#cite_note-moreexcept-2): `As a result, copy-initialization is usually equivalent to direct-initialization in terms of performance`. Note that the citation is from Herb Sutter's book `More Exceptional C++`.

Comment: I stand corrected on the optimization question, but I maintain that the copy-initialization version is bad style.  `Business bs2 = Business(2,businessName2);` still looks to me like somebody meant to declare a heap variable and forgot the splat and `new`.  Why not use the traditional form and avoid confusion?