# Why can write expressions like string s = "xxx" in C++?

Tags: c++, string, implicit-conversion

I often see that:

```
string str = "123";
```

My question is if `string` is a class type, why can we directly set it equal to `"123"` instead of using `new` or directly initialize it?

I am used to seeing something like

```
classType *pt = new classType;
classType pt = classType();
```

not

```
classType s = value;
```

Comment: C++ does have `new`, but it's no longer in widespread use (unlike Java).

Answer (score 9):

The C++ string type has an implicit conversion constructor that accepts as input a `const char *`.  Consequently, it is legal to initialize a C++ string using a C-style string, because C++ will interpret this as a call to the implicit conversion constructor.

In this case, the code

```
string str = "123";
```

is equivalent to

```
string str("123");
```

which more explicitly looks like a constructor call.

Note that it is extremely rare to see something like

```
classType p = classType();
```

The more proper way to say this would be to just write

```
classType p;
```

which implicitly calls the default, no-argument constructor.

Hope this helps!

Comment: is string str = "123" is different with string str("123")? due to direct initial or copy initial?

Comment: @jiafu- The two should be completely equivalent to one another.

Comment: why?  I know int x(1) is different with int x=1, why in this case it is same?

Comment: `int x = 1` and `int x(1)` are equivalent in c++ because they are built in types. Check out this link for more on the different between copy initialization and assignment initialization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati