# Why am I not provided with a default copy constructor from a volatile?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, volatile

This code:

```
class X {
  int member;  
};

volatile X a;
X b = a;
```

Fails with the error:

```
prog.cpp:6:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘X::X(volatile X&)’
prog.cpp:6:7: note: candidates are:
prog.cpp:1:7: note: X::X()
prog.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
prog.cpp:1:7: note: X::X(const X&)
prog.cpp:1:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘volatile X’ to ‘const X&’
```

Is there any way I can get the compiler to generate a volatile copy constructor for me?

Comment: You need to declare `b`as `volatile`.

Comment: But I want a non-volatile copy!

Comment: `volatile X&` cannot be converted to `const X&` because the two qualifiers contradict each other: `const` says "read it once, it's not going to change", while `volatile` says "read it every time, because it can change". There must be some smart rule in the C++ standard that prohibits making this conversion implicitly.

Comment: Surely const says "I won't change it", and volatile says someone else might.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: So what does `const volatile &X` mean then?

Comment: It is strange that copying from volatile types is allowed by default for integral types, but not even casting explicitly works for UDTs.

Comment: @Eric: It means you are not going to write that value, still the compiler should not optimize away apparently redundant reads because the value may change between two reads (even if `x` is not a shared variable)

Comment: I also need to disagree with "`const` says 'read it once, it's not going to change'".  A `const X&` reference does NOT allow that sort of optimization in any context where it wouldn't also be valid for a plain `X&` reference.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: There is no contradiction. `const` merely prevents modification, and `volatile` merely means reads and writes are observable. `const volatile` is a read-only variable, where reading the variable is observable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short answer is: Because the standard says you won't.

The C++ Standard 12.8/9 (Draft N3242) tells:

> The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class X will have the form
>
> - *X::X(const X&)*
>
> if
>
> - each direct or virtual base class B of X has a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type const
>     B& or const volatile B&, and
> - for all the non-static data members of X that are of a class type M (or array thereof), each such class
>     type has a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type const M& or const volatile M&. *[Note: 119]*
>
> Otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy constructor will have the form
>
> - *X::X(X&)*

Note 119 says:

> This implies that **the reference parameter of the implicitly-declared copy constructor cannot bind to a volatile lvalue**;
>   see *C.1.9*.

In C.1.9 you'll find:

> The implicitly-declared copy constructor and implicitly-declared copy assignment operator cannot make a
>   copy of a volatile lvalue. For example, the following is valid in ISO C:

```
struct X { int i; };
volatile struct X x1 = {0};
struct X x2(x1); // invalid C++
struct X x3;
x3 = x1; // also invalid C++
```

> **Rationale:** Several alternatives were debated at length. Changing the parameter to volatile const X& would greatly complicate the generation of efficient code for class objects. Discussion of providing two alternative signatures for these implicitly-defined operations raised unanswered concerns about creating ambiguities and complicating the rules that specify the formation of these operators according to the bases and members.

Comment: "In C.1.9 you'll find" - That doesn't make much sense to me. C doesn't have copy constructors. Never mind, I've just noticed that you're referring to the Annex C of the C++ standard.

Answer (score -3):

The key problem is that you provide no **assignment constructor**. Consequently, the compiler generate a **default** one for you:

```
X& X::operator =(const X& x){
   this.member = x.member;
   return *this;
}
```

The default assignment constructor accepts argument type as **const X&** in which the **const** is a **low-level const** and won't be ignored as **top-level const**.

Your code `X b = a` means to call the default constructor. But your argument `a` has type **volatile X** (can be converted to **volatile X &** and **volatile const X &**) cannot be converted to **const X&** implicitly.

So you should define your own assignment constructor as

```
X& X::operator =(volatile const X&);
```

---

**EDIT**
It shocks me that so many guys think the **copy constructor** (or call **copy initialization**) is called when using **assignment operator**.
Maybe call it **assignment operator** is not common. However, what I care is which method is called.

You can refer to this post:[Copy constructors, assignment operators, and exception safe assignment](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/) and [Default assignment operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/55098/)

---

EDIT
I made a mistake previously.
`X b = a` is just a initialization process. No assignment is involved.
Apologize for my error message.

Comment: Nope. A constructor like `X (volatile const X &x) : member(x.member) { }` will be required since `X b = a;` is copy-initialization. There is no such thing like "assignment constructor". There is either a constructor or an assignment operator.

Comment: @Pixelchemist What you provide is called "copy constructor". These two are different things. It is called **rule of three** in C++.

Comment: The rule of three mainly applies to classes managing resources. In this case a non-explicit copy constructor is required to do the conversion from volatile X to X.

Comment: @Pixelchemist Yeah. Rule of three mainly applies to classes with resources. The author use assignment operator (i.e. =) to construct a new object. Assignment constructor should be called.

Comment: There is no _"assignment constructor"_. [Read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati)

Comment: @Pixelchemist Yes. From [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/) and [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/55098/), we see it is called "assignment operator" which is called when using "=" to assignment one instance to another.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32092/discussion-between-zack-and-pixelchemist)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to take into account that the proper solution is to define a copy constructor taking a volatile. This would be better than writing something false and then add errata to it.