# Can I add an implicit conversion from a volatile T to a T?

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

[This code](http://ideone.com/Q1qswW)

```
struct T {
    int m_x;
    T(int x) : m_x(x) {}

    operator T() {
        return T(0);
    }
};

int main() {
    volatile T v(2);

    T nv(1);
    nv = v; // nv.m_x = 0
}
```

Gives:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:14:10: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘nv = v’
prog.cpp:14:10: note: candidates are:
prog.cpp:1:8: note: T& T::operator=(const T&)
prog.cpp:1:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘volatile T’ to ‘const T&’
prog.cpp:1:8: note: T& T::operator=(T&&)
prog.cpp:1:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘volatile T’ to ‘T&&’
```

What typecast overload do I need to define for this to work?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think you write `operator T() volatile`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Can't it do `nv.operator=(n.operator T())`?

Comment: I don't think `operator T` will ever be called, because there's no reason to convert a `T` to a `T`.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I'm quite sure about that too, and even more, even if it "worked", it would be pointless because the original `volatile` prevents the variable from being optimized either, no matter what you convert it to later.

Comment: @Eric Are you waiting for any further information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The short answer:

### Yes you can but the compiler won't do the job for you.

#### **You cannot have an compiler-provided conversion from volatile T to T but a user-defined implicit conversion using a volatile-qualified constructor.**

---

*It is also impossible to declare such a conversion by using explicitly-defaulted versions of the special member functions (see long answer for reference).*

You'll have to provide a user-defined way of conversion to enable such assignments. You can either

- use a non-explicit copy constructor with a cv-qualified argument for implicit user-defined conversion or
- a copy assignment operator taking a v-qualified argument.

Example:

```
X (X const volatile & xo);
X& operator= (X const volatile & xo);
```

---

## The long answer with standard quotes 'n stuff or

### why doesn't the compiler do this for me?

### Way 1: User-provided constructor from volatile T

#### Standard, ISO 14882:2011, 4/3

> An expression **`e`** can be implicitly converted to a type T if and only if the declaration **`T t=e;`** is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable t (8.5).

Since the declaration `T t = e;`, where in this case `e` is typed `volatile T`, requires such a copy-initialization to be valid, you'll need a copy constructor from a volatile T.

I already answered ([Why am I not provided with a default copy constructor from a volatile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217300/why-am-i-not-provided-with-a-default-copy-constructor-from-a-volatile/17218983#17218983)).
Therefore you'll need to provide a user-defined way of copy-initialization of T from volatile T.

```
X (X const volatile & xo);
```

*Note:*

- This is a declaration, you'll also have to provide a definition.
- The constructor must not be explicit.
- Providing an user-defined copy constructor taking a volatile argument will result in the abscence of an implicitly generated default assignment operator.

This will make your assignment work.

### Way 2: User-provided copy assignment operator from volatile T

Another way to make the assignment of your example code work is a copy assignment operator.

Unfortunatelly, **the standard also does say that a compiler will not provide implicit copy assignment operators for the conversion of volatile to non volatile objects.**

#### Standard, ISO 14882:2011, 12.8/18

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4). The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy constructor or a user-declared destructor. The implicitly declared copy assignment operator for a class X will have the form
>
> **X& X::operator=(const X&)**
>
> if
>
> - each direct base class B of X has a copy assignment operator whose parameter is of type const B&, const volatile B& or B, and
> - for all the non-static data members of X that are of a class type M (or array thereof), each such class type has a copy assignment operator whose parameter is of type const M&, const volatile M& or M. **<sup>122</sup>**
>
> Otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator will have the form
>
> **X& X::operator=(X&)**

#### Note 122 on 12.8/18

> **the reference parameter of the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator cannot bind to a volatile lvalue; see *C.1.9*.**

In the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217300/why-am-i-not-provided-with-a-default-copy-constructor-from-a-volatile/17218983#17218983) I quoted C.1.9 where it says:

> The implicitly-declared copy constructor **and implicitly-declared copy assignment operator** cannot make a copy of a volatile lvalue. [ ... ]

The result is that we'll have to provide a suitable copy assignment operator if we want to have one.

```
X& operator= (X const volatile & xo);
```

---

**Also note that you cannot declare an assignment/constructor from volatile explicitly-defaulted.**

#### C++11 Standard 8.4.2/1

> A function that is explicitly defaulted shall
>
> - be a special member function,
> - have the same declared function type (except for possibly differing ref-qualifiers and except that in the case of a copy constructor or copy assignment operator, the parameter type may be “reference to non-const T”, where T is the name of the member function’s class) as if it had been implicitly declared, and
> - not have default arguments.

The following Note was removed from the final C++11 standard but was present in the Draft N3242. It still holds.

> [ Note: **This implies that** parameter types, return type, and **cv-qualifiers must match the hypothetical implicit declaration.** —end note ]

Since the hypothetical implicit declaration is non-volatile you cannot have the defaulted.

Comment: And so to fix this one simply does...?

Comment: Provide a user-defined assignment operator taking a volatile argument?

Comment: @MooingDuck The only way to do it is user-defined conversion but that is not what I would consider "simple" if the question is about implcit conversion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `X (X const volatile & xo);` is a function that does implicit conversions, making your whole answer quite misleading.

Comment: Most of your standards quotes are about implicit or defaulted _functions_, which have virtually nothing to do with implicit _conversions_.

Comment: My interpretation of the question was that OP is looking for a way having the compiler dealing with the conversion. A non-explicit constructor with cv-qualified argument will do the trick since the compiler will use it in the assignment (as I pointed out in my answer) to convert the type.

Comment: @MooingDuck I nevertheless got your point and restructured my answer for a better compliance with the question. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I'd misunderstood bits.  This answer is actually _really_ good now

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you get a copy constructor and copy assignment that allows a volatile source:

```
struct X {
  X(const X& o) : members(o.members) {}
  X(const volatile X& o) : members(o.members) {}
  X& operator=(const X& o) {v=o.v; return *this;}
  X& operator=(const volatile X& o) {v=o.v; return *this;}
};
```

Note though that this has some consequences. The type is no longer POD or even trivially copyable, for one. Which might defeat the whole point of making it volatile.

Comment: I'm afraid this is ill-formed

Comment: Huh, how so? Isn't it recognized as a copy ctor form?

Comment: [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3afd3f9e0a2b89ba6e447753e61da11a-0f732321323bad263acad699748475b5) is what Clang is saying

Comment: Well, that's very explicit. I also found the standardese in [dcl.fct.def.default]p1 bullet 2.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I'm afraid that's not sufficient for the OP though (they are trying to do an assignment)

Comment: @SebastianRedl Andy Prowl is right. I just added the standard information on explicitly-defaulted functions regarding cv-qualifiers to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the assignment operator `=`:

```
T& operator=(const volatile T &rhs) {
    m_x = rhs.m_x;
    return *this;
}
```