# Assigning a volatile to a non-volatile and vice versa

Tags: c++, volatile

I want to profile a certain function and in order to get more reliable results I call the function in a loop. I was concerned that the compiler would see that I never use the result and optimize away my loop, so I thought I could just copy the result to a variable marked as volatile to prevent that ([demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0efedce68a04e29d)).

```cpp
#include <chrono>

struct Bar{};
Bar foo();

Bar profile_foo()
{
    // result is marked volatile so the loop isn't optimized away
    volatile Bar result;

    for(int i = 0; i< 10000; i++)
        result = foo();

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto begin = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto result = profile_foo();

    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto time_passed = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end-begin).count();

    // validate result ...
}
```

Turns out there is no default copy constructor/assignment operator between a volatile/non-volatile instance of a class. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217300/why-am-i-not-provided-with-a-default-copy-constructor-from-a-volatile/17218983#17218983).

So,

1. is there any other way to assign a non-volatile to a volatile and vice versa? Or,
2. is there another way to tell the compiler not to optimize away the loop?

**Note:** I cannot modify the class Bar.

Comment: Does Bar have a data member that is POD? So you could do something like `volatile double temp;` `temp = foo().getSomeDouble()` ?

Comment: If the function `foo` has explicit side effects or if it is defined in another compilation unit (the compiler cannot know whether side effects are present), the loop should not be optimized out.

Comment: @serge-ballesta foo might not have side effects and resides in a static lib. I think that aggresive link time optimization might still decide to optimize away.

Comment: @ryanp That might work. That could then be generalized to `volatile Bar* tmp; tmp = &result;`.