# indexing an element from a volatile struct doesn't work in C++

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
typedef struct {
    int test;
} SensorData_t;
volatile SensorData_t sensorData[10];

SensorData_t getNextSensorData(int i)
{
    SensorData_t data = sensorData[i];
    return data;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

}
```

It compiles with gcc version 8.3, but not with g++. Error message:

```
main.c: In function ‘SensorData_t getNextSensorData(int)’:
main.c:8:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘SensorData_t(volatile SensorData_t&)’
  SensorData_t data = sensorData[i];
                                  ^
main.c:3:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr SensorData_t::SensorData_t(const SensorData_t&)’ <near match>
 } SensorData_t;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:3:3: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.c:8:34: error: binding reference of type ‘const SensorData_t&’ to ‘volatile SensorData_t’ discards qualifiers
  SensorData_t data = sensorData[i];
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
main.c:3:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr SensorData_t::SensorData_t(SensorData_t&&)’ <near match>
 } SensorData_t;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:3:3: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.c:8:34: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘SensorData_t&&’ to lvalue of type ‘volatile SensorData_t’
  SensorData_t data = sensorData[i];
```

I'm not sure if I need to add volatile as well for the `data` variable and the return type, shouldn't be needed because it is copied. But I do access the sensorData array from an interrupt as well (on an embedded system), so I think I need `volatile` for the top level variable sensorData.

Comment: FYI: "typedef struct" is not required in C++. Also, one question concerning the code here: You could use a simple `int` array (or, better, `std::array`), do you have the struct here because it contains more members? In any case, you may need actual synchronization with the interrupt, even if it's just one `int`, so plan your critical section where only one of the two can access the data.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17217300/951890

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your program is trying to copy a `SensorData_t` object. The compiler supplies a copy constructor with the following signature:

```
SensorData_t(const SensorData_t &)
```

This copy constructor will not work with `volatile` arguments, hence the compilation error.

You can write your own copy constructor which works with `volatile` `SensorData_t` objects (as well as non-`volatile` `SensorData_t` objects):

```
struct SensorData_t {
    SensorData_t() = default;

    SensorData_t(const volatile SensorData_t &other)
        : test(other.test) {
    }

    int test;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, you may consider avoid copying the data from the array altogether, if the `getNextSensorData` is a simple *getter* function for the global `sensorData`:

```
// Intorduce type alias
using SD = const volatile SensorData_t&;

SD getNextSensorData(int i)
{
    return sensorData[i];
}
```

This way (if it is suitable for the design), you'll keep the definitions code more concise. But I have to note that the usage is a bit less direct than in the copy case:

```
int main() {
    // Type alias
    SD sd1 = getNextSensorData(0);
    // Deduced type
    auto&& sd2 = getNextSensorData(1);
    // Explicit type
    const volatile SensorData_t& sd3 = getNextSensorData(2);
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, since it moves the actual access to the volatile object from the "get" abstraction to some unknown point later in the code.  `volatile` strongly suggests that either the timing or order of access is critical.