# why do I need copy constructor here

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc4

I have a helper class for freeing MYSQL_RES handles.

```
class auto_mysqlres
{
public:
  auto_mysqlres(MYSQL_RES *res) : m_res(res)
  {
  }

  ~auto_mysqlres()
  {
    if (m_res != NULL)
      mysql_free_result(m_res);
  }

  operator MYSQL_RES* ()
  {
    return m_res;
  }

private:
  auto_mysqlres& operator= (const auto_mysqlres &res);
  auto_mysqlres (const auto_mysqlres &res);

private:
  MYSQL_RES *m_res;
};
```

when I try to use it this way
`auto_mysqlres result = return_pointer_to_mysql_res();`
I get the error in `GCC 4.6.3: auto_mysqlres::auto_mysqlres(const auto_mysqlres&) is private`. no errors in MSVC 2008, though.

`return_pointer_to_mysql_res` returns `MYSQL_RES*`, of course
I have fixed the problem with this line `auto_mysqlres result (return_pointer_to_mysql_res());`

but I want to find out why I get that error. I can't understand why GCC creates a temporary object there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are performing *copy initialization* here:

```
auto_mysqlres result = return_pointer_to_mysql_res();
```

This requires that a copy constructor be available, even if copies are elided. Semantically, you are constructing a temporary `auto_mysqlres` from a pointer on the RHS, and copy constructing from it on the LHS.

You can use *direct initialization* instead:

```
auto_mysqlres result(return_pointer_to_mysql_res());
```

see more on [copy initialization and direct initializazion here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm).

As @Rapptz points out in a comment, in C++11, you could decide to make your class move copyable (and possibly move assignable), in which case the move copy constructor would be picked up in the copy initialization.

Comment: Alternatively they can define move constructors and assignment. It'll implicitly delete the copy and allow for that initialization to take place since the function will return a temporary. However, I don't know if GCC 4.6.3 supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. @myself: Learning never stops. :)

Your constructor is not explicit and therefore a way to implicitly convert a `MYSQL_RES*` into as `auto_mysqlres`. This is what gcc does here. It converts the `MYSQL_RES*` into a `auto_mysqlres` and then tries to call the copy constructor. This is required here.

#### § 8.5 [dcl.init] / 14

> The initialization that occurs in the form
>
> - T x = a;
>
> [...] is called copy-initialization.

You copy-inititalize your object.

#### § 8.5 [dcl.init] / 16

> [... If the initialization] is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered. [...]
>
> Otherwise (i.e., **for the remaining copy-initialization cases**), user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4, and the best one is chosen through overload resolution.

In your case `MYSQL_RES*` is not the same class as, or a derived class of the destination class (`auto_mysqlres`) so a conversion is required since the constructor isn't considered.

You'll either

- have to do direct initialization

  `auto_mysqlres result(return_pointer_to_mysql_res());`
- or provide a (move) copy constructor.

<sub>PS: Wasn't quite aware of `where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination`.</sub>

Comment: this generates error  conversion from ‘MYSQL_RES* {aka st_mysql_res*}’ to non-scalar type ‘auto_mysqlres’ requested

Comment: I can't see how making it explicit will help.

Comment: Woops, you're right. The constructor isn't considered if the types do not match. I corrected that.