# It seems at a glance that a constructor return an object

Tags: c++

There are many ways to initialize an object, one of which is calling a constructor of centain user-defined type. Here are the examples.

```
Hello my_hello = Hello(3);
Hello my_hello(3);
```

As you already know, a constructor doesn't return anything. However, as you look above, it seems that it does return its initialized object. Furthermore, the assignment operator makes it more suspicious because it means it copys the right-hand object to the left-hand object.

Am i guessing wrong? Would you please explain it?

Comment: Have you learned copy constructor?

Comment: Sometimes thoughts out of ignorance are so bewildering that it starts feeling the work of acute intelligence.

Comment: The former *does not* use assignment operator. It's called copy initialization while the latter is called direct initialization. Assignment operator can only be used on already constructed objects.

Comment: constructor constructing object

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration

```
Hello my_hello = Hello(3);
```

creates two objects. First a temporary object from `Hello(3)`, and this temporary object is then copied through the copy-constructor to `my_hello` followed by the destruction of the temporary object.

However, to further muddle up the water, this copying and destruction of the temporary object may actually not happen due to [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision), a very common compiler optimization.

Comment: Just calling a constructor without an instantiation yields a temporary object initialized by the constructor?

Comment: Thank you for such a kind explanation. By the way, i have an another question. What about this? int a = int(3); It is obvious that the int is not user-defined type. Therefore, int(3) is not calling a constructor. It's so complicated. :-(

Comment: @isbae93 It's just the same, it creates a temporary `int` with the value `3` and copies that to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

> As you already know, a constructor doesn't return anything.

This is strictly true, per Standard.

However, it's an awful lot simpler to consider a constructor for T as a function returning a T (or emplacing it, a'la `new` and placement `new`). This is essentially how they're both used and implemented.

Also, there is no assignment operator in your code. That is copy-initialization, which is not the same thing. The `my_hello` object is copied from `Hello(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

only one way to find out...try some code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

class Hello{
    public:
    Hello(int n)
    {
        printf("CTOR\n");
    }

    Hello& operator=(Hello& h)
    {
        printf("assignment\n");
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {

    printf("first:\n");
    Hello firstHello(3);

    printf("\nsecond:\n");
    Hello secondHello = Hello(4);

    return 0;
}
```

result :

```
first:
CTOR

second:
CTOR
```

i.e. no assignment operator called.
should really add a copy constructor and check that is used instead...consider it an exercise for the reader.

http://ideone.com/9Yr2WY

EDIT : out of curiosity, here is a version including a copy constructor.
In this case neither of the lines calls the copy constructor - as Joachim points out, the compiler has succeeded in optimizing out the copy :
http://ideone.com/wQ1VTK