# How to convert boost::units::metric::hour_base_unit to boost::units::si::time?

Tags: c++, boost-units

I would like to make the following code compile properly:

```
#include <boost/units/systems/si.hpp>
#include <boost/units/base_units/metric/hour.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  using namespace boost::units;
  quantity<si::time> t = 2.0 * metric::hour_base_unit::unit_type(); 
}
```

Using gcc, I get the following error:

```
error: conversion from ‘boost::units::multiply_typeof_helper<double, boost::units::unit<boost::units::list<boost::units::dim<boost::units::time_base_dimension, boost::units::static_rational<1l> >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>, boost::units::heterogeneous_system<boost::units::heterogeneous_system_impl<boost::units::list<boost::units::heterogeneous_system_dim<boost::units::scaled_base_unit<boost::units::si::second_base_unit, boost::units::scale<60l, boost::units::static_rational<2l> > >, boost::units::static_rational<1l> >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>, boost::units::list<boost::units::dim<boost::units::time_base_dimension, boost::units::static_rational<1l> >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>, boost::units::dimensionless_type> >, void> >::type {aka boost::units::quantity<boost::units::unit<boost::units::list<boost::units::dim<boost::units::time_base_dimension, boost::units::static_rational<1l> >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>, boost::units::heterogeneous_system<boost::units::heterogeneous_system_impl<boost::units::list<boost::units::heterogeneous_system_dim<boost::units::scaled_base_unit<boost::units::si::second_base_unit, boost::units::scale<60l, boost::units::static_rational<2l> > >, boost::units::static_rational<1l> >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>, boost::units::list<boost::units::dim<boost::units::time_base_dimension, boost::units::static_rational<1l> >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>, boost::units::dimensionless_type> >, void>, double>}’ to non-scalar type ‘boost::units::quantity<boost::units::unit<boost::units::list<boost::units::dim<boost::units::time_base_dimension, boost::units::static_rational<1l> >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>, boost::units::homogeneous_system<boost::units::list<boost::units::si::meter_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::scaled_base_unit<boost::units::cgs::gram_base_unit, boost::units::scale<10l, boost::units::static_rational<3l> > >, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::second_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::ampere_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::kelvin_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::mole_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::si::candela_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::radian_base_unit, boost::units::list<boost::units::angle::steradian_base_unit, boost::units::dimensionless_type> > > > > > > > > > > >’ requested
   quantity<si::time> t = 2.0 * metric::hour_base_unit::unit_type();
                               ^
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

A quick look through the documentation implies that most (if not all) conversions between `unit` classes are `explicit` (it's a [design decision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_units/FAQ.html#boost_units.FAQ.ExplicitConversions)). Therefore, you can use direct-initiliazation instead of copy-initialization:

```
#include <boost/units/systems/si.hpp>
#include <boost/units/base_units/metric/hour.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  using namespace boost::units;
  quantity<si::time,double> xxxxxx (2.0 * metric::hour_base_unit::unit_type());
}
```

And it works.

The reason why this works while your attempt doesn't is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) That would solve the issue with this particular C++ file but I was trying to solve an another issue where a more complex expression was used. What I really want is an easy way to turn on implicit conversion (metric hour is a scaled unit of si::seconds) without using BOOST_UNITS_DEFINE_CONVERSION_FACTOR.

Comment: I find strange that there is no constants named `metric::liter` defined in the library. `namespace boost::units::metric{liter_base_unit::unit_type liter{};}`.