# struct constructor error, why use default constructor function will call a error?

Tags: c++, struct

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Foo{
    Foo(){}
    Foo(int){}
    void fun(){}
};

void main()
{
    Foo a(10);
    a.fun();
    Foo b();
    b.fun();//error
    Foo c = Foo(); // this is the right way to use default constructor?
    c.fun();
}
```

The code has an error when compiling, because `b` is not a type of class, who can tell me what is `b`? And the meaning of `Foo b()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is commonly known as C++ ["most vexing parse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

```
Foo b();
```

This declares a function named `b` returning `Foo`.

It should be just;

```
Foo b;
```

This will declare a variable `b` of type `Foo` that will be default initialised (`Foo` has a default constructor). `Foo c = Foo();` yes, this is an alternative default initialisation ([copy initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1051379/3747990)) but it is generally used more with POD data types.

It is worth noting that with C++11 (uniform initialisation), the following will compile and is possibly an alternative for you

```
Foo b{};
```

But it does the same thing in this case (with respect to constructing `b`).

Comment: This is vexing, but doesn't quite qualify as *most vexing*.

Comment: @T.C., :), Scott did write that around 2001, so in the 13 or so years since, things may have got worse...

Comment: `std::vector<T> v(std::istream_iterator<T>(ifs), std::istream_iterator<T>());` is the standard "most vexing" example :)

Answer (score 0):

The right way should be:

```
Foo b;
```

You just declared a function named `b`.